# How do I "toggle" through enum variants?

Tags: rust

I'd like to write a function which toggles/switches the provided value to the next in the enum and wraps around at the end:

```
enum Direction { NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST }
```

For example, `NORTH` => `SOUTH`, `SOUTH` => `EAST`, `EAST` => `WEST`, `WEST` => `NORTH`.

Is there an easier way than manually creating a static array as described in [In Rust, is there a way to iterate through the values of an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371534/in-rust-is-there-a-way-to-iterate-through-the-values-of-an-enum)

```
use Direction::*;
static DIRECTIONS: [Direction; 4] = [NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST];
```

Aren't enums suppose to be "enumerated"? I vaguely remember seeing an example before in Rust, but I can't seem to find it. Since Rust enums are more like unions/variants, I guess this complicates things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Rust, is there a way to iterate through the values of an enum?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371534/in-rust-is-there-a-way-to-iterate-through-the-values-of-an-enum)

Comment: it should be possible to do it unsafely: `let d : Direction =  unsafe {std::mem::transmute((NORTH as u8) + 1) }; // SOUTH`. Use at your own risk...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess something like this will do the trick:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate num_derive;
extern crate num_traits;

use num_traits::FromPrimitive;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, FromPrimitive)]
enum Direction {
    NORTH = 0,
    SOUTH,
    EAST,
    WEST,
}

fn turn(d: Direction) -> Direction {
    FromPrimitive::from_u8((d as u8 + 1) % 4).unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    use Direction::*;
    for &d in [NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST].iter() {
        println!("{:?} -> {:?}", d, turn(d));
    }
}
```

This does not require `unsafe` as it uses the automatically derived `FromPrimitive` trait.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a safe way (which is why I wrote a comment instead of proposing the unsafe transmute as an answer), but your method still relies on creating an array with all the enum's variants, which OP mentions as a possibility he's already aware of

Comment: @PaoloFalabella, what do you mean, it requires creating an array? It doesn't; the array is there just to illustrate the point. The main work is done in `turn()` function which is safe and does not use arrays.

Answer (score 16):

I would prefer to explicitly encode the next direction via a `match` statement:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Direction {
    North,
    South,
    East,
    West,
}

impl Direction {
    fn turn(&self) -> Self {
        use Direction::*;
        match *self {
            North => South,
            South => East,
            East => West,
            West => North,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    use Direction::*;

    for i in &[North, South, East, West] {
        println!("{:?} -> {:?}", i, i.turn());
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice use of `use` here. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

Vladimir's answer is correct but the programmer must remember to change the magic number "4" when adding a new member to the `enum`. This definition for `turn` should be easier to maintain:

```
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, FromPrimitive)]
enum Direction {
    NORTH = 0,
    SOUTH,
    EAST,
    WEST,
}

fn turn(d: Direction) -> Direction {
    match FromPrimitive::from_u8(d as u8 + 1) {
        Some(d2) => d2,
        None => FromPrimitive::from_u8(0).unwrap(),
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your solution! Your solution is arguably more resistent to change (bit more verbose, but still easy to reason about). Thanks!