# What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?

Tags: rust

The following Rust code compiles and runs without any issues.

```
fn main() {
    let text = "abc";
    println!("{}", text.split(' ').take(2).count());
}
```

After that, I tried something like this .... but it didn't compile

```
fn main() {
    let text = "word1 word2 word3";
    println!("{}", to_words(text).take(2).count());
}

fn to_words(text: &str) -> &Iterator<Item = &str> {
    &(text.split(' '))
}
```

The main problem is that I'm not sure what return type the function `to_words()` should have. The compiler says:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `count` found for type `std::iter::Take<std::iter::Iterator<Item=&str>>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:3:43
  |
3 |     println!("{}", to_words(text).take(2).count());
  |                                           ^^^^^
  |
  = note: the method `count` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
          `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&str> : std::marker::Sized`
          `std::iter::Take<std::iter::Iterator<Item=&str>> : std::iter::Iterator`
```

What would be the correct code to make this run? .... and where is my knowledge gap?

Answer (score 266, accepted):

I've found it useful to let the compiler guide me:

```
fn to_words(text: &str) { // Note no return type
    text.split(' ')
}
```

Compiling gives:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:5:5
  |
5 |     text.split(' ')
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected (), found struct `std::str::Split`
  |
  = note: expected type `()`
             found type `std::str::Split<'_, char>`
help: try adding a semicolon
  |
5 |     text.split(' ');
  |                    ^
help: try adding a return type
  |
3 | fn to_words(text: &str) -> std::str::Split<'_, char> {
  |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Following the compiler's suggestion and copy-pasting that as my return type (with a little cleanup):

```
use std::str;

fn to_words(text: &str) -> str::Split<'_, char> {
    text.split(' ')
}
```

The problem is that you cannot return a trait like `Iterator` because a trait doesn't have a size. That means that Rust doesn't know how much space to allocate for the type. You [cannot return a reference to a local variable, either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682876/is-there-any-way-to-return-a-reference-to-a-variable-created-in-a-function), so returning `&dyn Iterator` is a non-starter.

#### Impl trait

As of Rust 1.26, you can use [`impl trait`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1522-conservative-impl-trait.md):

```
fn to_words<'a>(text: &'a str) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a str> {
    text.split(' ')
}

fn main() {
    let text = "word1 word2 word3";
    println!("{}", to_words(text).take(2).count());
}
```

There are restrictions on how this can be used. You can only return a single type (no conditionals!) and it must be used on a free function or an inherent implementation.

#### Boxed

If you don't mind losing a little bit of efficiency, you can return a `Box<dyn Iterator>`:

```
fn to_words<'a>(text: &'a str) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a str> + 'a> {
    Box::new(text.split(' '))
}

fn main() {
    let text = "word1 word2 word3";
    println!("{}", to_words(text).take(2).count());
}
```

This is the primary option that allows for *dynamic dispatch*. That is, the exact implementation of the code is decided at run-time, rather than compile-time. That means this is suitable for cases where you need to return more than one concrete type of iterator based on a condition.

#### Newtype

```
use std::str;

struct Wrapper<'a>(str::Split<'a, char>);

impl<'a> Iterator for Wrapper<'a> {
    type Item = &'a str;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a str> {
        self.0.next()
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        self.0.size_hint()
    }
}

fn to_words(text: &str) -> Wrapper<'_> {
    Wrapper(text.split(' '))
}

fn main() {
    let text = "word1 word2 word3";
    println!("{}", to_words(text).take(2).count());
}
```

#### Type alias

As [pointed out by reem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535289/correct-way-to-return-an-iterator#comment43509185_27535594)

```
use std::str;

type MyIter<'a> = str::Split<'a, char>;

fn to_words(text: &str) -> MyIter<'_> {
    text.split(' ')
}

fn main() {
    let text = "word1 word2 word3";
    println!("{}", to_words(text).take(2).count());
}
```

#### Dealing with closures

When `impl Trait` isn't available for use, closures make things more complicated. Closures create anonymous types and these cannot be named in the return type:

```
fn odd_numbers() -> () {
    (0..100).filter(|&v| v % 2 != 0)
}
```

```
found type `std::iter::Filter<std::ops::Range<{integer}>, [closure@src/lib.rs:4:21: 4:36]>`
```

In certain cases, these closures can be replaced with functions, which can be named:

```
fn odd_numbers() -> () {
    fn f(&v: &i32) -> bool {
        v % 2 != 0
    }
    (0..100).filter(f as fn(v: &i32) -> bool)
}
```

```
found type `std::iter::Filter<std::ops::Range<i32>, for<'r> fn(&'r i32) -> bool>`
```

And following the above advice:

```
use std::{iter::Filter, ops::Range};

type Odds = Filter<Range<i32>, fn(&i32) -> bool>;

fn odd_numbers() -> Odds {
    fn f(&v: &i32) -> bool {
        v % 2 != 0
    }
    (0..100).filter(f as fn(v: &i32) -> bool)
}
```

#### Dealing with conditionals

If you need to conditionally choose an iterator, refer to [Conditionally iterate over one of several possible iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29760668/155423).

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot. The "trick" to let the compiler guide you is pretty useful, I will definitely use it in the future. ... and yes, this is seriously ugly! I hope that RFC makes it to the release candidate.

Comment: While wrapper types can be nice to hide complexity, I find it better to just use `type` aliases instead, since using a newtype means your  Iterator won't implement traits like `RandomAccessIterator` even if the underlying Iterator does.

Comment: @reem: Can `type` aliases support "template" parameters though? Because here `Wrapper` is parametrized over `'a`.

Comment: Yup! Type aliases support generic parameters. For instance, many libraries do `type LibraryResult<T> = Result<T, LibraryError>` as a convenience similar to `IoResult<T>`, which is also just a type alias.

Comment: Could you please clarify why one has to add a `'a` lifetime to `Box`? What does that mean? I always thought this was for bounds only, to say "T may only depend on something living at least as long as `'a`".

Comment: @torkleyy perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/q/27790168/155423 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/27675554/155423 would answer your question? If not, I'd encourage you to search for your question, and if you can't find it, ask a new one.

Comment: When returning an `impl Iterator` with a non-reference type the lifetime specifier needs to added in the end, like this: `fn make_iter<'a>(in: &'a mut ...) -> impl Iterator<Item = String> + 'a { ... }`.

Comment: Still not sure about the blessed method to pass iterators up the stack. Still unsure how the `impl` keyword and boxes interact, and still unsure which is preferred and why. Still unsure where the iterators are supposed to be rooted on the stack and where this might impact which methods of passing an iterator further up might be warranted.

Comment: @duane tl;dr use `impl Iterator` when you can (no indirection, no allocation), then use `Box<dyn Iterator>` when the compiler makes you. Terms like "rooted on the stack" don't have established meaning in Rust, so I don't know what you mean. My closest guess is you mean references / lifetimes but without examples there's nothing to go on.

Comment: What does `Iterator<Item = &'a str> + 'a` mean?

Answer (score 4):

Add to @Shepmaster answer. If you need closure and closure capture some args you can use this example

```
fn find_endpoint<'r>(
    descriptors: &'r mut rusb::EndpointDescriptors<'r>,
    direction: rusb::Direction,
) -> FilterMap<
    &mut rusb::EndpointDescriptors<'_>,
    impl FnMut(rusb::EndpointDescriptor<'r>) -> Option<u8>,
> {
    descriptors.filter_map(move |ep| {
        if ep.direction() == direction {
            Some(ep.address())
        } else {
            None
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I've been looking for this solution for months, thanks mate!