# Iterate over a string, n elements at a time

Tags: string, iterator, rust

I'm trying to iterate over a string, but iterating in slices of length `n` instead of iterator over every character. The following code accomplishes this manually, but is there a more functional way to do this?

```
fn main() {
    let string = "AAABBBCCC";
    let offset = 3;
    for (i, _) in string.chars().enumerate() {
        if i % offset == 0 {
            println!("{}", &string[i..(i+offset)]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is `.chunks()` but it is only available for slices, not general iterators.

Comment: That would be perfect if it were available for `&str`

Comment: What behavior do you want when the string is not evenly dividable into `N` characters? Your current code panicks.

Comment: Also, **please** be aware of issues with bytes / characters / graphemes *whenever* you start splitting strings.

Comment: @Shepmaster in my use case, either returning `None` or truncating the end would work. And yeah good points about bytes vs chars. Again, for my use case it works since I'm dealing with DNA sequence data but in general what I'm doing above is not unicode safe.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would use a combination of `Peekable` and `Take`:

```
fn main() {
    let string = "AAABBBCCC";
    let mut z = string.chars().peekable();
    while z.peek().is_some() {
        let chunk: String = z.by_ref().take(3).collect();
        println!("{}", chunk);
    }
}
```

In other cases, [`Itertools::chunks`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.7.6/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.chunks) might do the trick:

```
extern crate itertools;

use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let string = "AAABBBCCC";
    for chunk in &string.chars().chunks(3) {
        for c in chunk {
            print!("{}", c);
        }
        println!();
    }
}
```

### Standard warning about splitting strings

Be aware of issues with bytes / characters / code points / graphemes whenever you start splitting strings. With anything more complicated than ASCII characters, one character is **not** one byte and string slicing operates **on bytes**! There is also the concept of Unicode code points, but multiple Unicode characters may combine to form what a human thinks of as a single character. This stuff is **non-trivial**.

If you actually just have ASCII data, it may be worth it to store it as such, perhaps in a `Vec<u8>`. At the very least, I'd create a newtype that wraps a `&str` and only exposes ASCII-safe method and validates that it is ASCII when created.

Comment: I really like that this is safe across bytes/chars/graphemes. It doesn't really matter for my use case but in general this seems like the most complete solution.

Comment: how is this safe across graphemes?

Comment: @ker I think @anders means the *algorithm* is safe. To actually make it so, you'd have to swap `graphemes` instead of `chars`.

Answer (score 2):

`chunks()` is not available for `&str` because it is not really well-defined on strings - do you want chunks with length in bytes, or characters, or grapheme clusters? If you know in advance that your string is in ASCII you can use the following code:

```
use std::str;

fn main() {
    let string = "AAABBBCCC";
    for chunk in str_chunks(string, 3) {
        println!("{}", chunk);
    }
}

fn str_chunks<'a>(s: &'a str, n: usize) -> Box<Iterator<Item=&'a str>+'a> {
    Box::new(s.as_bytes().chunks(n).map(|c| str::from_utf8(c).unwrap()))
}
```

However, it will break immediately if your strings have non-ASCII characters inside them. I'm pretty sure that it is possible to implement an iterator which splits a string into chunks of code points or grapheme clusters - it is just there is no such thing in the standard library now.

Comment: This seems like the shortest way to accomplish my goal. As stated above I'm dealing with genomic sequence data, which is plain ASCII. I'm going to accept the other answer since it's more general, but I really like this.

Comment: Can you explain what the `<Item=&'a str>+'a` syntax does here? Also, why do you have to wrap the Iterator in a Box?

Comment: Ok I understand why you wrapped the iterator in a Box ([this link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/943814)). Still wondering about the other though.

Comment: @anders, yeah, I wrapped the iterator in a box because there is a `map` with a closure (though it could be written with a static function instead, so this is more for simplicity than of necessity). `Box<Iterator<Item=&'a str>+'a>` describes a type of a boxed trait object created out of a value which implements `Iterator<Item=&'a str>` and which has lifetime at least `'a` (the `+'a` part). The `<Item=&'a str>` syntax is the way to specify the desired associated type in a trait (here, the type of iterator items).

Answer (score 2):

You can always implement your own iterator. Of course that still requires quite some code, but it's not at the location where you are working with the string. Therefor your loop stays readable.

```
#![feature(collections)]

struct StringChunks<'a> {
    s: &'a str,
    step: usize,
    n: usize,
}

impl<'a> StringChunks<'a> {
    fn new(s: &'a str, step: usize) -> StringChunks<'a> {
        StringChunks {
            s: s,
            step: step,
            n: s.chars().count(),
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for StringChunks<'a> {
    type Item = &'a str;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a str> {
        if self.step > self.n {
            return None;
        }
        let ret = self.s.slice_chars(0, self.step);
        self.s = self.s.slice_chars(self.step, self.n);
        self.n -= self.step;
        Some(ret)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let string = "AAABBBCCC";
    for s in StringChunks::new(string, 3) {
        println!("{}", s);
    }
}
```

Note that this splits after `n` unicode chars. So graphemes or similar might end up split up.

Comment: I like this, but the plain function is more concise.

Comment: that it is, but my version also is zero-copy ;)