# Conditionally iterate over one of several possible iterators

Tags: rust

I'm trying to switch behavior based on an `Option` input to a function. The idea is to iterate based on whether or not a given `Option` is present. Here's a minimal, if silly, example:

```
use std::iter;

fn main() {
    let x: Option<i64> = None;

    // Repeat x 5 times if present, otherwise count from 1 to 5
    for i in match x {
        None => 1..5,
        Some(x) => iter::repeat(x).take(5),
    } {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

I get an error:

```
error[E0308]: match arms have incompatible types
  --> src/main.rs:7:14
   |
7  |       for i in match x {
   |  ______________^
8  | |         None => 1..5,
9  | |         Some(x) => iter::repeat(x).take(5),
   | |                    ----------------------- match arm with an incompatible type
10 | |     } {
   | |_____^ expected struct `std::ops::Range`, found struct `std::iter::Take`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::ops::Range<{integer}>`
              found type `std::iter::Take<std::iter::Repeat<i64>>`
```

This makes perfect sense, of course, but I'd really like to choose my iterator based on a condition, since the code in the for-loop is non-trivial and copy-pasting all of that just to change iterator selection would be pretty ugly and unmaintainable.

I tried using `as Iterator<Item = i64>` on both arms, but that gives me an error about unsized types because it's a trait object. Is there an easy way to go about this?

I could, of course, use `.collect()` since they return the same type and iterate over that vector. Which is a good quick fix, but for large lists seems a bit excessive.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The most straightforward solution is to use a *trait object*:

```
use std::iter;

fn main() {
    let mut a;
    let mut b;

    let x: Option<i64> = None;

    // Repeat x 5 times if present, otherwise count from 1 to 5
    let iter: &mut dyn Iterator<Item = i64> = match x {
        None => {
            a = 1..5;
            &mut a
        }
        Some(x) => {
            b = iter::repeat(x).take(5);
            &mut b
        }
    };

    for i in iter {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

The main downside for this solution is that you have to allocate stack space for each concrete type you have. This also means variables for each type. A good thing is that only the used type needs to be initialized.

The same idea but requiring heap allocation is to use *boxed trait objects*:

```
use std::iter;

fn main() {
    let x: Option<i64> = None;

    // Repeat x 5 times if present, otherwise count from 1 to 5
    let iter: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = i64>> = match x {
        None => Box::new(1..5),
        Some(x) => Box::new(iter::repeat(x).take(5)),
    };

    for i in iter {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

This is mostly useful when you want to [return the iterator from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423). The stack space taken is a single pointer, and only the needed heap space will be allocated.

You can also [use an enum for each possible concrete iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50204370/155423).

Answer (score 31):

The [either crate](https://crates.io/crates/either) provides the [`Either`](https://docs.rs/either/1.5.0/either/enum.Either.html) type. If both halves of `Either` are iterators, then so is the `Either`:

```
extern crate either;

use either::Either;
use std::iter;

fn main() {
    let x: Option<i64> = None;

    // Repeat x 5 times if present, otherwise count from 1 to 5
    let iter = match x {
        None => Either::Left(1..5),
        Some(x) => Either::Right(iter::repeat(x).take(5)),
    };

    for i in iter {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

Like [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29760740/155423), this still takes stack space for each concrete type you have. However, you don't need individual variables for each concrete value.

This type can also be [returned from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423), unlike the trait object references. Compared to boxed trait objects, it will always use a fixed size on the stack, regardless of which concrete type was chosen.

You'll find this type (or semantic equivalent) in other places as well, such as [`futures::Either`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.2.1/futures/future/enum.Either.html)

Comment: I like Shep's other answer below since it generalizes to more than just 2 iterators.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq you can make an `Either<Either<A, B>, C>`, etc.

Comment: When returning the iterator from a function and that function is recursive (in a way that the concrete types would also be recursive), this solution doesn't work but the `Box<dyn Iterator>` one does.

Answer (score 25):

Personally, rather than use `Either`, I often prefer to create a series of `Option<Iterator>` values that get chained together. Something like this:

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=383380d045de10db472ab2408fecb671&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015)

```
use std::iter;

fn main() {
    let x: Option<i64> = None;

    // Repeat x 5 times if present, otherwise count from 1 to 5
    for i in pick(x) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}

fn pick(opt_x: Option<i64>) -> impl Iterator<Item = i64> {
    let iter_a = if let None = opt_x {
        Some(1..5)  
    } else {
        None
    };

    let iter_b = if let Some(x) = opt_x {
        Some(iter::repeat(x).take(5))
    } else {
        None
    };

    iter_a.into_iter().flatten().chain(iter_b.into_iter().flatten())
}
```

It's a bit less obvious than using `Either`, but it avoids another crate, and sometimes it works out quite elegantly.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=1c2165f28db26919ef157bbe19603cbb ?

Answer (score 13):

Here is a variation of @Niko's brilliant solution using a single `match` expression instead of several `if let` expressions, which may be more convenient when dealing with more conditional cases:

```rust
use std::iter;

fn main() {
    let x: Option<i64> = None;

    // Repeat x 5 times if present, otherwise count from 1 to 5
    for i in pick(x) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}

fn pick(opt_x: Option<i64>) -> impl Iterator<Item = i64> {
    let mut iter_a = None;
    let mut iter_b = None;

    match opt_x {
        None => iter_a = Some(1..5),
        Some(x) => iter_b = Some(iter::repeat(x).take(5)),
    }

    iter_a.into_iter().flatten().chain(iter_b.into_iter().flatten())
}
```

Comment: There are more `mut`s in this version than @Niko's, but I suppose it doesn't really matter. :)