# Is it possible to conditionally apply iterator transformations?

Tags: iterator, rust

I have a function that takes array of posts and an optional `after_id` to skip posts with an id less or equal to given.

```
fn get_page<'a>(data: &'a Vec<u64>, after_id: Option<u64>) -> Vec<&u64> {
    let data = data.iter();
    let data = match after_id {
        Some(id) => data.skip_while(|&&post| post <= id),
        None => data,
    };

    data.take(10).collect()
}
```

This code triggers a compilation error, stating that `Some` arm creates a `iter::SkipWhile` struct and its type is incompatible with `posts` type (`slice::Iter`) from `None` arm.

The only fix I see, without deconstructing `match` into `if`s or something like that, is:

```
let posts = match after_id {
    Some(id) => posts.skip_while(|post| post.id <= id).collect(),
    None => posts.collect(),
};
```

The obvious downside is that I needlessly iterate whole collection and use extra memory.

Is it possible to apply `skip_while` conditionally and store the result in a single variable, without `collect`ing an intermediate result?

Comment: See also [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec) or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423).

Comment: I believe your question is already answered by the answers of [Iterate over one of several possible iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29760668/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise we can mark this as answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks for your comments and edits!

Seems like the answer you provided is exactly what I'm looking for, so I'm marking this answered :)