# How do I conditionally return different types of futures?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, future, control-flow

I have a method that, depending on a predicate, will return one future or another. In other words, an if-else expression that returns a future:

```
extern crate futures; // 0.1.23

use futures::{future, Future};

fn f() -> impl Future<Item = usize, Error = ()> {
    if 1 > 0 {
        future::ok(2).map(|x| x)
    } else {
        future::ok(10).and_then(|x| future::ok(x + 2))
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile:

```
error[E0308]: if and else have incompatible types
  --> src/lib.rs:6:5
   |
6  | /     if 1 > 0 {
7  | |         future::ok(2).map(|x| x)
8  | |     } else {
9  | |         future::ok(10).and_then(|x| future::ok(x + 2))
10 | |     }
   | |_____^ expected struct `futures::Map`, found struct `futures::AndThen`
   |
   = note: expected type `futures::Map<futures::FutureResult<{integer}, _>, [closure@src/lib.rs:7:27: 7:32]>`
              found type `futures::AndThen<futures::FutureResult<{integer}, _>, futures::FutureResult<{integer}, _>, [closure@src/lib.rs:9:33: 9:54]>`
```

The futures are created differently, and might hold closures, so their types are not equal. Ideally, the solution wouldn't use `Box`es, since the rest of my async logic doesn't use them.

How is if-else logic in futures normally done?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Using `async`/`await`

Since Rust 1.39, you can use `async` and `await` syntax to cover most cases:

```rust
async fn a() -> usize {
    2
}
async fn b() -> usize {
    10
}

async fn f() -> usize {
    if 1 > 0 {
        a().await
    } else {
        b().await + 2
    }
}
```

See also:

- [What is the purpose of async/await in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52835725/155423)

## `Either`

Using [`futures::future::Either`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/enum.Either.html) via the [`FutureExt`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html) trait has no additional heap allocation:

```
use futures::{Future, FutureExt}; // 0.3.5

async fn a() -> usize {
    2
}

async fn b() -> usize {
    10
}

fn f() -> impl Future<Output = usize> {
    if 1 > 0 {
        a().left_future()
    } else {
        b().right_future()
    }
}
```

However, this requires a fixed stack allocation. If `A` takes 1 byte and happens 99% of the time, but `B` takes up 512 bytes, your `Either` will *always* take up 512 bytes (plus some). This isn't always a win.

This solution also works for `Stream`s.

## Boxed trait objects

Here we use [`FutureExt::boxed`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.boxed) to return a trait object:

```
use futures::{Future, FutureExt}; // 0.3.5

async fn a() -> usize {
    2
}

async fn b() -> usize {
    10
}

fn f() -> impl Future<Output = usize> {
    if 1 > 0 {
        a().boxed()
    } else {
        b().boxed()
    }
}
```

This solution also works for `Stream`s.

---

As [Matthieu M. points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51885745/how-do-i-conditionally-return-different-types-of-futures/51885804?noredirect=1#comment90730137_51885804), the two solutions can be combined:

> I would note that there is a middle ground solution for the case of a large `B`: `Either(A, Box<B>)`. This way, you only pay for the heap allocation on the rare case where it's a `B`

Note that you can also stack `Either`s if you have more than 2 conditions (`Either<A, Either<B, C>>`; `Either<Either<A, B>, Either<C, D>>`, etc.):

```
use futures::{Future, FutureExt}; // 0.3.5

async fn a() -> i32 {
    2
}

async fn b() -> i32 {
    0
}

async fn c() -> i32 {
    -2
}

fn f(v: i32) -> impl Future<Output = i32> {
    use std::cmp::Ordering;

    match v.cmp(&0) {
        Ordering::Less => a().left_future(),
        Ordering::Equal => b().left_future().right_future(),
        Ordering::Greater => c().right_future().right_future(),
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Conditionally iterate over one of several possible iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29760668/155423)

Comment: I would note that there is a middle ground solution for the case of a large `B`: `Either(A, Box<B>)`. This way, you only pay for the heap allocation on the rare case where it's a B.

Comment: In case of odd number of conditions you can define `Either<A, Empty<_, _>>`

Comment: @LukaszGuminski the examples I give handle 3 (odd) and 4 (even) conditions: *if you have more than 2 conditions (`Either<A, Either<B, C>>`; `Either<Either<A, B>, Either<C, D>>`, etc.)* . I don't understand why you are using `Empty`.

Comment: @Shepmaster I tried to say that `Either<Either<A, B>, C>` could be written as `Either<Either<A, B>, Either<C, Empty<_, _>>>`. But now actually I am not sure if it is any better. The Either types are equally nested, but this doesn't seem to be an advantage. I think I overcomplicated.

Comment: @LukaszGuminski in the absence of other information, I'd think that the version with less code in play (`Either<A, Either<B, C>>`) would be better.

Comment: @Shepmaster I agree.

Comment: @Shepmaster Can you provide an example of nesting `Either` when there are early returns with `Either`.