# Converting a future result in another future

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a function that returns a future with a `User` trait. I have two concrete implementations of it: `AnonymousUser` and `BaseUser`. To get the `BaseUser`, after authentication, I have to go to the database and fetch it, which may or not succeed, and return the new future with the correct type. I've tried the following ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9093a8fea7e786c15a4e68e5fa5ec61e&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)):

```
extern crate futures; // 0.1.23
extern crate rand; // 0.5.4

use futures::future::{ok, Future};
use std::io::Error;

trait User {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct AnonymousUser;
impl User for AnonymousUser {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct BaseUser;
impl User for BaseUser {}

fn fetch_base_user() -> impl Future<Item = BaseUser, Error = Error> {
    ok(BaseUser)
}

fn run_future() -> impl Future<Item = impl User, Error = Error> {
    match rand::random::<bool>() {
        true => fetch_base_user().from_err().then(move |res| match res {
            Ok(user) => ok(user),
            Err(_) => ok(AnonymousUser),
        }),
        false => ok(AnonymousUser),
    }
}

fn main() {
    run_future().and_then(move |user| println!("User {:?}", user));
}
```

this failed because the return of the `then` function expects a `BaseUser`:

```
error[E0308]: match arms have incompatible types
  --> src/main.rs:23:62
   |
23 |           true => fetch_base_user().from_err().then(move |res| match res {
   |  ______________________________________________________________^
24 | |             Ok(user) => ok(user),
25 | |             Err(_) => ok(AnonymousUser),
   | |                       ----------------- match arm with an incompatible type
26 | |         }),
   | |_________^ expected struct `BaseUser`, found struct `AnonymousUser`
   |
   = note: expected type `futures::FutureResult<BaseUser, _>`
              found type `futures::FutureResult<AnonymousUser, _>`
```

I tried forcing the return type:

```
use futures::future::FutureResult;

fn run_future() -> impl Future<Item=impl User, Error=Error> {
    match rand::random::<bool>() {
        true => fetch_base_user().from_err().then(move |res| ->
        FutureResult<impl User, Error> { // Forcing the result type here
            match res {
                Ok(user) => ok(user),
                Err(_) => ok(AnonymousUser),
            }
        }),
        false => ok(AnonymousUser),
    }
}
```

which fails with:

```
error[E0562]: `impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and inherent method return types
  --> src/main.rs:27:22
   |
27 |         FutureResult<impl User, Error> { // Forcing the result type here
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^
```

I've tried to rework using `Box`es for the return, which almost worked ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6a80a01d7c20969952929d894d78eeff&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

```
fn run_future() -> impl Future<Item = Box<impl User>, Error = Error> {
    match rand::random::<bool>() {
        true => fetch_base_user()
            .from_err()
            .then(move |res| -> FutureResult<Box<User>, Error> {
                match res {
                    Ok(user) => ok(Box::new(user) as Box<User>),
                    Err(_) => ok(Box::new(AnonymousUser) as Box<User>),
                }
            }),
        false => ok(Box::new(AnonymousUser) as Box<User>),
    }
}
```

which fails with

```
error[E0308]: match arms have incompatible types
  --> src/main.rs:22:5
   |
22 | /     match rand::random::<bool>() {
23 | |         true => fetch_base_user().from_err().then(move |res| match res {
24 | |             Ok(user) => ok(Box::new(user) as Box<User>),
25 | |             Err(_) => ok(Box::new(AnonymousUser) as Box<User>),
26 | |         }),
27 | |         false => ok(Box::new(AnonymousUser) as Box<User>),
   | |                  ---------------------------------------- match arm with an incompatible type
28 | |     }
   | |_____^ expected struct `futures::Then`, found struct `futures::FutureResult`
   |
   = note: expected type `futures::Then<futures::future::FromErr<impl futures::Future, _>, futures::FutureResult<std::boxed::Box<User>, _>, [closure@src/main.rs:23:51: 26:10]>`
              found type `futures::FutureResult<std::boxed::Box<User>, _>`
```

So I guess it's only a matter of forcing both to be the same result type

Comment: Potentially a duplicate of [How do I conditionally return different types of futures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51885745/155423).

Comment: @loganfsmyth I've updated the question with more information.

Comment: @Shepmaster indeed, with Either I've managed to make it work. After my last update, do you think it's possible to use `impl User` or I have to use `Box<User>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I conditionally return different types of futures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51885745/how-do-i-conditionally-return-different-types-of-futures)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end the comment from shepmaster led me to the response through this other question: [How do I conditionally return different types of futures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51885745/155423)

Basically using Either::A and Either::B solves the issue. I still couldn't make it work without boxing the parameters but this might be a different question.