# Why can impl trait not be used to return multiple / conditional types?

Tags: rust, traits, return-type

I'm trying to get a random number generator. Since `OsRng::new()` can fail, I'd like to fall back to `thread_rng()` if I have to:

```
extern crate rand; // 0.5.5

use rand::{thread_rng, OsRng, RngCore};

fn rng() -> impl RngCore
{
    match OsRng::new() {
        Ok(rng) => rng,
        Err(e) => thread_rng()
    }
}
```

However, I get this error message which I cannot understand:

```
error[E0308]: match arms have incompatible types
 --> src/lib.rs:6:5
  |
6 | /     match OsRng::new() {
7 | |         Ok(rng) => rng,
8 | |         Err(e) => thread_rng(),
  | |                   ------------ match arm with an incompatible type
9 | |     }
  | |_____^ expected struct `rand::OsRng`, found struct `rand::ThreadRng`
  |
  = note: expected type `rand::OsRng`
             found type `rand::ThreadRng`
```

Why is the compiler expecting `rand::OsRng` here instead of an implementation of `RngCore`? If I remove the `match` and directly return `thread_rng()`, I don't get above error message.

I do not believe that this is a duplicate of [How do I return an instance of a trait from a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30661046/3755692), as the other question is asking about **how** one can return a trait from a function, and this question is about **why** the compiler will not allow me to return a trait but wants me to return an `OsRng` which is not the return type of the function.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`impl Trait` is not equivalent to returning an interface or base class object.  It's a way of saying "I don't want to write the name of the specific type I'm returning".  You're still returning a value of a single, specific type; you just aren't saying *which* type.

Each of those branches is returning different types, hence the problem.  Implementing the same trait is not enough.

What you likely want in this specific case is a trait object like `Box<dyn RngCore>`.

```
extern crate rand; // 0.6.5

use rand::{rngs::OsRng, thread_rng, RngCore};

fn rng() -> Box<dyn RngCore> {
    match OsRng::new() {
        Ok(rng) => Box::new(rng),
        Err(_) => Box::new(thread_rng()),
    }
}
```

**Note**: if you are using a slightly older version of Rust, you may need to remove the `dyn` keyword.  It's optional in the previous (2015) edition of Rust.

Comment: What is the `dyn` keyword doing? It works just fine without it

Comment: Technically, it's redundant.  It was introduced to "clarify" what the code means: `dyn RngCore` is a dynamically dispatched type derived from the `RngCore` trait.  `dyn` will be required in a future edition of Rust.  It's exactly the sort of thing Shepmaster will edit, so I might as well get it over with now.

Answer (score 15):

[DK. has already explained *why*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52018925/155423), but I'd like to provide an alternative workaround.

As mentioned in [Conditionally iterate over one of several possible iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760668/conditionally-iterate-over-one-of-several-possible-iterators), you can create an enum that implements a trait if both of its component types do. For example:

```
extern crate rand; // 0.6.5

use rand::{rngs::OsRng, thread_rng, RngCore};

fn rng() -> impl RngCore {
    match OsRng::new() {
        Ok(rng) => EitherRng::Left(rng),
        Err(_) => EitherRng::Right(thread_rng()),
    }
}

enum EitherRng<L, R> {
    Left(L),
    Right(R),
}

impl<L, R> RngCore for EitherRng<L, R>
where
    L: RngCore,
    R: RngCore,
{
    fn next_u32(&mut self) -> u32 {
        match self {
            EitherRng::Left(l) => l.next_u32(),
            EitherRng::Right(r) => r.next_u32(),
        }
    }

    fn next_u64(&mut self) -> u64 {
        match self {
            EitherRng::Left(l) => l.next_u64(),
            EitherRng::Right(r) => r.next_u64(),
        }
    }

    fn fill_bytes(&mut self, b: &mut [u8]) {
        match self {
            EitherRng::Left(l) => l.fill_bytes(b),
            EitherRng::Right(r) => r.fill_bytes(b),
        }
    }

    fn try_fill_bytes(&mut self, b: &mut [u8]) -> Result<(), rand::Error> {
        match self {
            EitherRng::Left(l) => l.try_fill_bytes(b),
            EitherRng::Right(r) => r.try_fill_bytes(b),
        }
    }
}
```

The [either crate](https://crates.io/crates/either) provides a lot of these types of implementations for fundamental traits.

See also:

- [How do I conditionally return different types of futures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51885745/155423)