# How to return impl trait wrapped inside Result?

Tags: rust, traits

I have a function that reads in some content either from a file or from the web, and returns the contents. For simplicity, let's use the following which is just for a file:

```
fn test() -> Result<Vec<u8>, Error> {
    let mut buf = Vec::new();
    // Does some things that may error ...
    File::open("test.txt")?.read_to_end(&mut buf)?;
    Ok(buf)
}
```

Is it possible to write this function such that it returns the `Read` trait wrapped inside `Result` instead so that it does not need to immediately read the full contents into memory?

Comment: In the future, you are encouraged to try to solve your own problem before asking it and show some of your effort in the question.

Comment: Well, of course I've tried to solve this problem, but as the Rust compiler is very picky, the half dozen variations I tried all resulted in errors that didn't lead in the right direction. Perhaps in the future I will chronicle all my attempts as a part of my question to prove I've not put no thought into it.

Comment: @Listerone We can only consider effort that is visible in the question. In fact, the point of showing research effort is not as much about the effort done as it is about transmitting this effort to the question. In this case, we would expect you to show the examples of code that had failed to compile.

Answer (score 6):

> How to return impl trait wrapped inside Result?

By *returning an impl trait wrapped inside `Result`*:

```
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{self, Read},
};

fn test() -> io::Result<impl Read> {
    let f = File::open("test.txt")?;
    Ok(f)
}
```

See also:

- [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423)
- [Why can impl trait not be used to return multiple / conditional types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52001592/155423)

Comment: I actually spent 5 hours today trying to accomplish exactly this, and I've tried this, but due to another error, I was convinced Rust just did not support it, despite having made **significant** effort, which eventually led me here, with the intent of posting a similar question. I imagine it might have been the same for the OP. Anyhow, thanks!