# How to join_all from a Vec of closures that return asyncs?

Tags: rust, async-await

I want to generate a `Vec` of `.await`s and execute them with `join_all`:

```rust
use futures::future::join_all; // 0.3.5
use std::future::Future;

async fn hello(name: &str) -> String {
    format!("Hello {}!", name)
}

async fn main() {
    let urls = vec!["Peter", "Hans", "Jake"];
    let mut requests: Vec<Box<dyn Fn() -> Box<dyn Future<Output = String>>>> = vec![];
    for url in urls {
        requests.push(Box::new(|| Box::new(hello(&url))));
    }
    let responses: Vec<String> = join_all(requests).await;

    println!("Response: {:?}", responses);
}
```

I get the error message:

```
error[E0277]: `dyn std::ops::Fn() -> std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::string::String>>` cannot be unpinned
  --> src/main.rs:15:45
   |
15 |     let responses : Vec<String>  = join_all(requests).await;
   |                                             ^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Unpin` is not implemented for `dyn std::ops::Fn() -> std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::string::String>>`
   | 
  ::: /playground/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/futures-util-0.3.5/src/future/join_all.rs:83:14
   |
83 |     I::Item: Future,
   |              ------ required by this bound in `futures::future::join_all`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `futures::Future` for `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::ops::Fn() -> std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::string::String>>>`

error[E0277]: `dyn std::ops::Fn() -> std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::string::String>>` is not a future
  --> src/main.rs:15:45
   |
15 |     let responses : Vec<String>  = join_all(requests).await;
   |                                             ^^^^^^^^ `dyn std::ops::Fn() -> std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::string::String>>` is not a future
   | 
  ::: /playground/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/futures-util-0.3.5/src/future/join_all.rs:83:14
   |
83 |     I::Item: Future,
   |              ------ required by this bound in `futures::future::join_all`
   |
   = help: the trait `futures::Future` is not implemented for `dyn std::ops::Fn() -> std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::string::String>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `futures::Future` for `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::ops::Fn() -> std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::string::String>>>`

error[E0277]: `dyn std::ops::Fn() -> std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::string::String>>` cannot be unpinned
  --> src/main.rs:15:36
   |
15 |     let responses : Vec<String>  = join_all(requests).await;
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Unpin` is not implemented for `dyn std::ops::Fn() -> std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::string::String>>`
   | 
  ::: /playground/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/futures-util-0.3.5/src/future/join_all.rs:28:8
   |
28 |     F: Future,
   |        ------ required by this bound in `futures::future::JoinAll`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `futures::Future` for `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::ops::Fn() -> std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::string::String>>>`

error[E0277]: `dyn std::ops::Fn() -> std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::string::String>>` is not a future
  --> src/main.rs:15:36
   |
15 |     let responses : Vec<String>  = join_all(requests).await;
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `dyn std::ops::Fn() -> std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::string::String>>` is not a future
   | 
  ::: /playground/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/futures-util-0.3.5/src/future/join_all.rs:28:8
   |
28 |     F: Future,
   |        ------ required by this bound in `futures::future::JoinAll`
   |
   = help: the trait `futures::Future` is not implemented for `dyn std::ops::Fn() -> std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::string::String>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `futures::Future` for `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::ops::Fn() -> std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::string::String>>>`

error[E0277]: `dyn std::ops::Fn() -> std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::string::String>>` cannot be unpinned
  --> src/main.rs:15:36
   |
15 |     let responses : Vec<String>  = join_all(requests).await;
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Unpin` is not implemented for `dyn std::ops::Fn() -> std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::string::String>>`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `futures::Future` for `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::ops::Fn() -> std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::string::String>>>`

error[E0277]: `dyn std::ops::Fn() -> std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::string::String>>` is not a future
  --> src/main.rs:15:36
   |
15 |     let responses : Vec<String>  = join_all(requests).await;
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `dyn std::ops::Fn() -> std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::string::String>>` is not a future
   |
   = help: the trait `futures::Future` is not implemented for `dyn std::ops::Fn() -> std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::string::String>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `futures::Future` for `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::ops::Fn() -> std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::string::String>>>`

error[E0277]: `main` has invalid return type `impl futures::Future`
 --> src/main.rs:9:17
  |
9 | async fn main() {
  |                 ^ `main` can only return types that implement `std::process::Termination`
  |
  = help: consider using `()`, or a `Result`

error[E0752]: `main` function is not allowed to be `async`
 --> src/main.rs:9:1
  |
9 | async fn main() {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `main` function is not allowed to be `async`
```

Comment: You're creating the vec to hold boxes of closures returning boxes, but trying to add there pins of boxes of closures returning pins of boxes. What do you gen if you simply replace `Box::pin` with `Box::new`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, then I get the error message (and others). I corrected my original post.

Answer (score 2):

`join_all` requires an iterator of futures, not an iterator of functions returning futures:

```rust
pub fn join_all<I>(i: I) -> JoinAll<<I as IntoIterator>::Item>
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    <I as IntoIterator>::Item: Future,
```

Additionally, your futures can't be pinned and so `join_all` cannot use them.

The shortest fix is to:

1. Call the closure
2. Pin the future

```rust
use futures::future; // 0.3.5
use std::{future::Future, pin::Pin};

async fn hello(name: &str) -> String {
    format!("Hello {}!", name)
}

pub async fn example() {
    let urls = vec!["Peter", "Hans", "Jake"];
    let mut requests: Vec<Box<dyn Fn() -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = String>>>>> = vec![];
    for url in urls {
        requests.push(Box::new(move || Box::pin(hello(&url))));
    }
    let responses: Vec<String> = future::join_all(requests.into_iter().map(|r| r())).await;

    println!("Response: {:?}", responses);
}
```

This can be written more succinctly as:

```rust
use futures::future::{self, FutureExt, LocalBoxFuture}; // 0.3.5

async fn hello(name: &str) -> String {
    format!("Hello {}!", name)
}

pub async fn example() {
    let urls = vec!["Peter", "Hans", "Jake"];
    let mut requests: Vec<Box<dyn Fn() -> LocalBoxFuture<'static, String>>> = vec![];
    for url in urls {
        requests.push(Box::new(move || hello(&url).boxed_local()));
    }
    let responses: Vec<String> = future::join_all(requests.into_iter().map(|r| r())).await;

    println!("Response: {:?}", responses);
}
```

However, none of that is needed for your specific example:

1. The closure doesn't provide any value
2. You have one type of future so there's no need for dynamic dispatch
3. You don't even need a `Vec`

```rust
use futures::future; // 0.3.5

async fn hello(name: &str) -> String {
    format!("Hello {}!", name)
}

pub async fn example() {
    let urls = vec!["Peter", "Hans", "Jake"];

    let hellos = urls.iter().map(|u| hello(u));
    let responses = future::join_all(hellos).await;

    println!("Response: {:?}", responses);
}
```

See also:

- [How can I put an async function into a map in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58704424/155423)
- [Cannot use `impl Future` to store async function in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58354633/155423)

Comment: Won't capture nay errors though.