# How can I put an async function into a map in Rust?

Tags: rust, async-await

I cannot handle async functions when writing an async router for `hyper`.

This code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::future::Future;

type BoxedResult<T> = Result<T, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>;
type CalcFn = Box<dyn Fn(i32, i32) -> dyn Future<Output = BoxedResult<i32>>>;

async fn add(a: i32, b: i32) -> BoxedResult<i32> {
    Ok(a + b)
}

async fn sub(a: i32, b: i32) -> BoxedResult<i32> {
    Ok(a - b)
}

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<&str, CalcFn> = Default::default();
    map.insert("add", Box::new(add));
    map.insert("sub", Box::new(sub));

    println!("map size: {}", map.len());
}
```

Generates the following compiler error:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<fn(i32, i32) -> impl std::future::Future {add} as std::ops::FnOnce<(i32, i32)>>::Output == dyn std::future::Future<Output = std::result::Result<i32, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync>>>`
  --> src/main.rs:17:23
   |
17 |     map.insert("add", Box::new(add));
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected opaque type, found trait std::future::Future
   |
   = note: expected type `impl std::future::Future`
              found type `dyn std::future::Future<Output = std::result::Result<i32, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync>>>`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn std::ops::Fn(i32, i32) -> dyn std::future::Future<Output = std::result::Result<i32, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync>>>`

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<fn(i32, i32) -> impl std::future::Future {sub} as std::ops::FnOnce<(i32, i32)>>::Output == dyn std::future::Future<Output = std::result::Result<i32, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync>>>`
  --> src/main.rs:18:23
   |
18 |     map.insert("sub", Box::new(sub));
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected opaque type, found trait std::future::Future
   |
   = note: expected type `impl std::future::Future`
              found type `dyn std::future::Future<Output = std::result::Result<i32, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync>>>`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn std::ops::Fn(i32, i32) -> dyn std::future::Future<Output = std::result::Result<i32, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync>>>`
```

It seems there is a conflict between `impl Future` and `dyn Future`, but I have no idea how to handle it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This happens because `impl Future` is a concrete unique type while `dyn Future` is an abstract type. `HashMap` expects the abstract type since it can only hold instances of a single type.

If we can box the return type of the async functions, we will able to add these futures into a `HashMap`.

First we need to change the type of `CalcFn`:

```rust
type CalcFn = Box<dyn Fn(i32, i32) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = i32>>>>;
```

Then this can do the trick:

```rust
let mut map: HashMap<&str, CalcFn> = Default::default();
map.insert("add", Box::new(|a, b| Box::pin(add(a, b))));
map.insert("sub", Box::new(|a, b| Box::pin(sub(a, b))));

println!("map size: {}", map.len());

//map.get("add").unwrap()(2, 3).await
```

This [complete example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b4581103ebb8afcecceaa66b329a9530)
simplified `Future`'s `Item` type, using an `i32` instead of a `Result`. Please also check the [full code for your case](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c52134926772edf1607f6484906331e5).

You can also use types from the futures crate like [`LocalBoxFuture`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/type.LocalBoxFuture.html) and [`BoxFuture`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/type.BoxFuture.html) created by the [`FutureExt::boxed`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.boxed) and [`FutureExt::boxed_local`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.boxed_local) methods respectively:

```rust
use futures::future::{FutureExt, LocalBoxFuture}; // 0.3.5
use std::collections::HashMap;

type BoxedResult<T> = Result<T, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>;
type CalcFn = Box<dyn Fn(i32, i32) -> LocalBoxFuture<'static, BoxedResult<i32>>>;

async fn add(a: i32, b: i32) -> BoxedResult<i32> {
    Ok(a + b)
}

async fn sub(a: i32, b: i32) -> BoxedResult<i32> {
    Ok(a - b)
}

async fn example() {
    let mut map: HashMap<&str, CalcFn> = Default::default();
    map.insert("add", Box::new(|a, b| add(a, b).boxed()));
    map.insert("sub", Box::new(|a, b| sub(a, b).boxed()));

    println!("map size: {}", map.len());

    //map.get("add").unwrap()(2, 3).await
}
```

Comment: Full [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7b42663108c1c18359c19c1fce16267d) with executor

Comment: See also [Why can impl trait not be used to return multiple / conditional types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52001592/155423); [How do I create a heterogeneous collection of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27957103/155423); [How can I have a collection of objects that differ by their associated type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28932450/155423).