# Lifetime issues with FuturesUnordered

Tags: rust, lifetime, self-reference

I'm trying to store these `Readable` instances on the `Coordinator` struct
and have a `schedule` method that picks one of the `readables` and pushes it into a FuturesUnordered instance (also inside `Coordinator`) to be pulled later.
Problem is: This doesn't compile due to a lifetime error

```
use bytes::Bytes;
use futures::prelude::stream::FuturesUnordered;
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;

struct Readable {}

impl Readable {
    async fn read(&mut self) -> Result<Bytes, ()> {
        Err(())
    }
}

type Futures = FuturesUnordered<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Bytes, ()>> + Send>>>;

struct Coordinator {
    readers: Vec<Readable>,
    futures: Futures,
}

impl Coordinator {
    fn schedule(&mut self) {
        let reader = self.readers.get_mut(0).unwrap();
        let f = Box::pin(reader.read());
        self.futures.push(f);
    }
}
```

error

```
error[E0759]: `self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
  --> src/lib.rs:23:22
   |
22 |     fn schedule(&mut self) {
   |                 --------- this data with an anonymous lifetime `'_`...
23 |         let reader = self.readers.get_mut(0).unwrap();
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...is captured here...
24 |         let f = Box::pin(reader.read());
25 |         self.futures.push(f);
   |                           - ...and is required to live as long as `'static` here

error: aborting due to previous error
```

link to playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2b69f519de1ac60b30bbbfb4a3cc3b7d

Anyone can help me understand why is this an issue?
Specifically, it seems to be complaining when I try to push into `FuturesUnordered` but I don't see any lifetime bounds on the push method:

```
    /// Push a future into the set.
    ///
    /// This method adds the given future to the set. This method will not
    /// call [`poll`](core::future::Future::poll) on the submitted future. The caller must
    /// ensure that [`FuturesUnordered::poll_next`](Stream::poll_next) is called
    /// in order to receive wake-up notifications for the given future.
    pub fn push(&self, future: Fut) {...}
```

I thought it could also be related to this particular struct having self references (ie: `Coordinator::futures` is referencing `Coordinator::readers`) but I don't fully understand if that's related.

Answer (score 0):

If we expand our async function it will be look like this:

```rust
fn read<'a>(&'a mut self) -> impl Future<Output = Result<Bytes, ()>> + 'a
```

As you can see the lifetime `'a` has captured in the returned `Future` type, this `'a` is an anonymous lifetime since this `read` function can be called from any location.

This leads to our problem;  from compiler perspective your `schedule` function creates a future with an anonymous lifetime, and tries to store it in `self`. It is **not related with** `FuturesUnordered` even if you would store your future like `self.futures = f` then the compiler would still throw the same error.

One solution can be using dedicating lifetime to tell compiler this is safe but I don't really suggest it because eventually it might lead any other problems since it forces borrowing self in a specific lifetime like in the code below.

```
impl<'a> Coordinator<'a> {
    fn schedule(&'a mut self) {//forced
        let reader = self.readers.get_mut(0).unwrap();
        let f = Box::pin(reader.read());
        self.futures = f;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6b4395eac2b12ae999d31e293d934bee)

Other solution is much easier if your future doesn't borrow anything, you can define your async function without lifetimes as a future builder.

```rust
impl Readable {
    fn read(&mut self) -> impl Future<Output = Result<Bytes, ()>> {
        //produce bytes from self 
        futures::future::err(())
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aaeffac6723bdf3893b9b1c04e366753)

**See also :**

- https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2394-async_await.html#lifetime-capture-in-the-anonymous-future
- [What is the concrete type of a future returned from `async fn`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58762210/what-is-the-concrete-type-of-a-future-returned-from-async-fn/58767047)