# Why does a Future from a member struct outlive the parent struct?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, lifetime

I want to provide an abstracted struct for writing records to a file. I want to be able to specify different format options for that file, so I use an enum to internally represent the actual writing operation on the file, while the outer struct mainly obtains records over some channel and enqueues them in a `FuturesUnordered` to have itself evaluated as a `Stream` from.

The problem I'm running into is that this enqueueing fails due to conflicting lifetimes and I can't figure out how to resolve them ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=242a1f76de753dd13585adf9ef668c11)):

```rust
use std::{pin::Pin, task::Poll};

use anyhow::Result;
//use csv_async::AsyncSerializer;
use futures::{Future, FutureExt, Stream, StreamExt};
use serde::Serialize;
use tokio::{
    fs::File as TokioFile,
    io::AsyncWriteExt,
};

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Record {
    timestamp: String,
    data: std::collections::HashMap<String, f64>,
}

enum WriterStrategy {
    RawFile(TokioFile),
    Csv/*(AsyncSerializer<TokioFile>)*/
}

impl WriterStrategy {
    async fn write(&mut self, records: &[Record]) -> Result<()> {
        match self {
            Self::Csv/*(ser)*/ => {
                /*for rec in records {
                    ser.serialize(rec).await?;
                }*/
                Ok(())
            },
            Self::RawFile(file) => {
                let mut write = String::new();
                for rec in records {
                    for (key, val) in &rec.data {
                        write.push_str(&format!("{} - {}: {}\n", rec.timestamp, key, val));
                    }
                }
                AsyncWriteExt::write(file, &write.as_bytes()).await.map(|_| ()).map_err(|e| e.into())
            },
        }
    }
}

struct FormatWriterStream<'a> {
    writer: WriterStrategy,
    channel: std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<Record>,
    open_queries: futures::stream::FuturesUnordered<
        Pin<Box<(dyn Future<Output = Result<()>> + Send + 'a)>>,
    >,
}

impl Stream for FormatWriterStream<'_> {
    type Item = Result<()>;

    fn poll_next(self: Pin<&mut Self>, c: &mut std::task::Context) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        let mut records = Vec::new();
        while let Ok(rec) = self.channel.try_recv() {
            records.push(rec);
        }
        self.open_queries.push(self.writer.write(&records).boxed());
    
        self.open_queries.poll_next_unpin(c)
    }
}
```

The compilation error on this particular version is a little misleading with the following output:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:61:32
   |
61 |         self.open_queries.push(self.writer.write(&records).boxed());
   |                                ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime defined on the method body at 56:28...
  --> src/lib.rs:56:28
   |
56 |     fn poll_next(self: Pin<&mut Self>, c: &mut std::task::Context) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that the reference type `&mut Pin<&mut FormatWriterStream<'_>>` does not outlive the data it points at
  --> src/lib.rs:61:32
   |
61 |         self.open_queries.push(self.writer.write(&records).boxed());
   |                                ^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'_` as defined on the impl at 53:36...
  --> src/lib.rs:53:36
   |
53 | impl Stream for FormatWriterStream<'_> {
   |                                    ^^
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/lib.rs:61:32
   |
61 |         self.open_queries.push(self.writer.write(&records).boxed());
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `Pin<Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = Result<(), anyhow::Error>> + std::marker::Send>>`
              found `Pin<Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = Result<(), anyhow::Error>> + std::marker::Send>>`
```

The problem becomes clearer when also using an explicit lifetime on the block `impl<'a> Stream for FormatWriterStream<'a>`, where it is pointed out that the `WriterStrategy`'s `write` function does not return a `Future` with a matching lifetime boundary (it would be expected to be `'static` if the explicit lifetime was removed from `FormatWriterStream`, which is certainly also not what I'd want).

I'm unable to find a way to match them somehow - I tried multiple approaches to get around the issue:

1. not stating the `write` function as `async` but instead explicitly returning a `Pin<Box<(dyn Future<Output = Result<()>> + Send + 'a)>>`, which requires both its arguments to have the `'a` lifetime, which cannot be reconciled with the strict `self: Pin<&mut Self>` requirement of the `poll_next` function.
2. moving away from the `enum` approach entirely and instead use a(n `async_`)`trait` that I'd implement on the structs wrapped by the enum thus far and have `FormatWriterStream`'s `writer` member be a `+ 'a`-bounded trait object, but also to no avail.

I have a similar construction working in a different module, however in that case the analogue of `FormatWriterStream` contains a proper `&'a` reference to the struct that produces the futures that get pushed into the `FuturesUnordered`, so the lifetimes work out. As it makes more sense for me to have the file handle be tied to its writer abstraction, I don't find it reasonable to set it up somewhere outside the scope of the `FormatWriterStream` and pass it in as a reference.

Why do the lifetimes of futures that are obtained from the `WriterStrategy` member struct conflict with the `FormatWriterStream`'s lifetime requirements? And is there some way I can make clearer to the compiler what I'm intending to do here?

I know that the control flow in the `poll_next` function is not very good. In my actual code I evaluate the channel based on an [`IntervalStream`](https://docs.rs/tokio-stream/0.1.6/tokio_stream/wrappers/struct.IntervalStream.html), but since it would complicate the already lengthy code sample even more, I decided to leave that part out.

I've come across [Lifetime issues with FuturesUnordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66897475/lifetime-issues-with-futuresunordered) (among others) but was not able to apply any of its answer's suggestions to my problem as hopefully demonstrated above

Comment: This is really really tricky... I wonder if sadly the only way to do this (without requiring heap allocation) is via a self-referential struct, which would require *extremely* tricky unsafe code. I could be wrong about that though. I wish I could be of more help here!