# How to specify an output type for a Future/async block?

Tags: rust

```
use tokio::runtime::Runtime;

// Create the runtime
let rt  = Runtime::new().unwrap();

// Execute the future, blocking the current thread until completion
let s = rt.block_on(async {
    println!("hello");
});
```

is it possible to specify an output type for a future block? On the code above, `s: ()`, but I wanted to be `Result<(), Error>` so I can return some error from inside the block.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? This looks like a XY problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the concrete type of a future returned from `async fn`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58762210/what-is-the-concrete-type-of-a-future-returned-from-async-fn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite familiar with `async rust`, but as far as I know, the return type of an `async fn` or `async block` is `impl Future<Output=TheRealReturnTypeOfFnBody>`. Once blocked on, as you did `rt.block_on(async block)`, the return type will become `TheRealReturnTypeOfFnBody`, therefore:

To make `s` have type `Result<(), Error>`, you have to implement it in the function body(i.e. make `TheRealReturnTypeOfFnBody` `Result<(), Error>`)

```rust
use tokio::runtime::Runtime;

fn main() {
    // Create the runtime
    let rt = Runtime::new().unwrap();

    // Execute the future, blocking the current thread until completion
    let s: () = rt.block_on(async {
        println!("hello");
    });

    let s_with_error_case: Result<(), &str> = rt.block_on(async {
        if false {
            Err("run into a trouble")
        } else {
            println!("erverything is fine");
            Ok(())
        }
    });

    if let Err(err_info) = s_with_error_case {
        eprintln!("{}", err_info);
    }
}
```