# How can I put an async function with a reference variable inside a function?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, functional-programming

The title should have already suggest you I have noticed [How can I put an async function into a map in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58704424/how-can-i-put-an-async-function-into-a-map-in-rust/58709332#58709332) and I have failed to proceed my work. Here is my sample code based on above link:

```
extern crate async_std;
use async_std::task;
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::boxed::Box;

type VarIn = &String;
type VarOut = String;
type FnType = Box< dyn Fn(VarIn) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=VarOut>>> >;

async fn test(v: FnType) {
    println!("{}", v("hi".to_string()).await)
}

async fn var(s: &String) -> String {
    format!("var:{}", s)
}

fn main() {
    task::block_on(test(Box::new(|s| Box::pin(var(s)))));
}
```

If `VarIn` is replaced by `String` instead of `&String` then everything is fine. However, my use case needs me to pass a reference instead to fulfill my usage (I use it in an infinite loop, so I can't pass the ownership to this function). What should I do to successfully pass the reference to async function, or there is some design to circumvent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify in the type definitions that are used in the function test what the lifetime of the reference is and how it relates to the `Future`.

```
VarIn<'a> = &'a String;
VarOut = String;
FnType<'a> = Box<dyn Fn(VarIn<'a>) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=VarOut> + 'a>>>;
```

This won't ultimately work, because the String created in `test` will be dropped at the bottom of the function, while the `&String` will be returned with the Future. You can use an `&str` and get this example to work, and that is what I suggest.

```
VarIn<'a> = &'a str
VarOut = String
FnType<'a> = Box<dyn Fn(VarIn<'a>) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=VarOut> + 'a>>>;
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d86d8b57b556c3d4c4e0282f890a2228