# unifying futures::future::map::Map and futures::future::result_::FutureResult

Tags: rust, rust-actix

I am using the following actix handler:

```rust
fn callback(info: web::Query<CallbackInfo>, session: Session) -> impl Future<Item = HttpResponse, Error = actix_web::Error>
```

Inside this function I do some branching and sometimes I return:

```rust
web::block(|| Result::<Backup, String>::Ok(run_backup(token_info)))
    .from_err()
    .map(|backup| HttpResponse::Ok().json(backup))
```

other times I return:

```rust
let r = HttpResponse::Found()
    .set_header(http::header::LOCATION, "/")
    .finish();
futures::future::ok(r)
```

Which fails to compile with

```
expected struct `futures::future::map::Map`, found struct `futures::future::result_::FutureResult`
```

Which I think I understand, even though it's weird that `.map` doesn't return another future. But how can I unify these two times so I can use them as return types?

Update:
It has been suggested this is a duplicate of: [Why can impl trait not be used to return multiple / conditional types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001592/why-can-impl-trait-not-be-used-to-return-multiple-conditional-types) But that question does not solve this problem, it only describes why this occurs. I see that the problem is with `impl Future`, but I cannot change this as I am using actix-web, which requires this signature, or a similar signature that I am not able to find out, hence why I ask this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can impl trait not be used to return multiple / conditional types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001592/why-can-impl-trait-not-be-used-to-return-multiple-conditional-types)

Comment: No, not really. impl Future is imposed on me by actix?

Comment: The actix-web book [handlers chapter](https://actix.rs/docs/handlers/) *Different return types (Either)* section might be of help for you. But without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), one can never be certain.

Comment: to be honest this is a bad question so downvoting is here to says this is a bad question. The duplicate is perfect, if you can't change your return type so the answer of shepmaster is for you.

Comment: Can you explain how this is a bad question?

Comment: @edwardw Yeah that works, thanks a lot I didn't see that in the docs.