# Declaring type of Vec of closures

Tags: rust, closures

I'd like to create a struct that can hold on to a bunch of closures for me to later use them. The closures should also have the `Clone` trait on them too.

What's the syntax for declaring that?

My attempt which doesn't compile:

```
pub struct Equations {
    eqns:Vec<impl Fn(f32) -> f32 + Clone>,
}
```

And another attempt, I can't quite get the required syntax here (or how to look it up).

```
trait AnonFunction: Fn(f32) -> f32 + Clone {}

pub struct Equations {
    eqns:Vec<dyn AnonFunction>,
}
```

Edit: Not sure why this was voted to be closed, I was linked to this question: [How to represent an opaque type in a struct field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74057864/how-to-represent-an-opaque-type-in-a-struct-field) which requires an understanding of async, macros, potentially the genawaiter crate just to understand what is being asked. And is a much longer question.

I think the question herein is simpler as it is only talking specifically about anonymous closures which suits the Q&A style format. I did go to the effort of making a simpler example, not just copying the code verbatim from my main project.

Comment: You should add the full compiler error message(s).

Comment: We might be getting somewhere with `pub struct Equations {eqns:Vec<Box<dyn Fn(f32) -> f32>>}`. But I still can't get `Clone` to work. If I add `Clone` via a supertrait, it complains of `this trait cannot be made into an object... ..because it requires 'Self: Sized'`.

Comment: Well it's either a trait object, or a generic. Not sure why you need `Clone` anyways since `&Fn()` also implements `Fn()`

Comment: Thanks. I can try without `Clone`, I've had issues when I `move` the equations it wanted `Clone` implemented.