# How do I create a reader factory able to return a generic Read trait in rust

Tags: rust

I am still very new to the rust language.
I would like to create a factory method able to return a generic Read trait in order to be able to read data from a serial device or a text file based on an option.
This is what I have written so far.

```
fn get_reader(name: &str, kind: ReaderType) -> Result<impl Read> {
    match kind {
        ReaderType::SerialDevice => {
            let mut serial_handler = serial::open(&name)?;
            serial_handler.configure(&SETTINGS)?;
            Ok(BufReader::new(serial_handler))
        },
        ReaderType::TraceFile => {
            let mut file_in = File::open(&name)?;
            Ok(BufReader::new(file_in))
        }
    }
}
```

My idea is to use this code to be able to read data from a serial device or from a file (for test purposes).

Then, I would like to use this reader to read data byte by byte:

```
fn next_sentence(mut reader: impl Read) -> String {
    let mut line = String::new();
    let mut c : [u8; 1] = [0x00];
    loop {
        match reader.read_exact(&mut c) {
            Ok(_) => {
                line.push(c[0] as char);
                if c[0] == b'\n' {
                    break;
                }
            },
            Err(_) => break
        };
    };

    line
}
```

This approach fails:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
--> src/gnss.rs:59:31
|
59 |             Ok(BufReader::new(file_in))
|                               ^^^^^^^ expected struct `gnss::serial::serial_unix::TTYPort`, found struct `std::fs::File`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

What is the correct way to handle this problem?

Comment: `impl Read` can return only _one_ implementation of `Read`, it can't pick&choose between the two. But you can return `Box<dyn Read>`, which will return an implementation that resolves to virtual calls.

Comment: Thanks. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks; I posted it as a comment because I expected it to be closed as dup, e.g. of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001592/why-can-impl-trait-not-be-used-to-return-multiple-conditional-types).