# What are the performance implications of .await on a Ready future?

Tags: performance, concurrency, rust, future

I'm using futures 0.3 and I would like to use a single trait that is implemented for both async scenarios and synchronous ones:

```rust
trait Testy {
    type FutType: Future<Output = i32>;

    fn stuff(&self) -> Self::FutType;
}

pub struct TestyImp;
impl Testy for TestyImp {
    type FutType = Ready<i32>;

    fn stuff(&self) -> Self::FutType {
        ready(3)
    }
}
```

How do I get from the Rust compiler's evaluation of `.await` on this `Ready` future back into the runtime (i.e. Tokio)?  Was I able to get straight to a `poll` call with an immediate result from a stack-based future state machine, or did it cost me something along the way?  Did the use of `Ready` introduce:

- heap allocations?
- a path through a chain of non-inlined function calls in the runtime?
- a run through an event loop?
- a thread context switch? (not synchronously scheduled is how I would think of this from a C# perspective)

Let's assume an intelligently designed runtime, or just assume Tokio if the answer is particularly dependent on it.

I've spent a lot of time in C# where we have `ValueTask` and `Task`.  `ValueTask` provides two major advantages: an already completed value that can be on the stack, and no entry into task runtime overhead when awaited with a preexisting value.  Hopefully that helps explain the motivation of my question.

Comment: Please read [What is the purpose of async/await in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52835725/155423). Calling `.await` in an async block/function really only creates a new anonymous type that implements `Future`. No event loop or threads are involved from `.await`.

Comment: So my mistake was thinking anything ever went back to the runtime with await, I see.  That drastically simplifies my understanding.  Thanks!  That eliminates 90% of my question, happy to accept that.

Comment: What is the remaining 10%? You may want to think about rewriting your question to focus on that 10%, linking to any existing resources (like the previously linked question) that you need to to frame your question.

Comment: Sorry, i mean you answered the 10%, 'How do i get from the Rust compiler's evaluation of .await...' and made the other 90% unapplicable.

Comment: Do you feel like this question has been suitably answered by the previously linked question? In that case, we can mark this as a duplicate.