# Why do I need async / await if I already have non-blocking IO like epoll / kqueue / IOCP?

Tags: rust, async-await, nonblocking

I have experience with the non-blocking IO library `epoll` and its high level abstraction `libuv`, so when I started learning Rust, I looked for Rust equivalents and found Mio. Mio works the way I understand about non-blocking IO and is familiar to me. I can easily use this kind of API to build high performance server applications using several threads or even a single thread.

Rust 1.39 brought the `async` / `await` syntax. I have read some articles and documentation on it and it feels like coroutines. I understand that `.await` can be used to yield CPU to do other things in the same thread, but there is no easy way to dynamically schedule code to run in that thread, it doesn't work in an evented way like `epoll`, with which I can register events in advance and get notified when those events happen.

The example for `async` / `await` of opening and reading files doesn't make sense to me, because in that example after `.await` I have nothing to do but **wait** for the content to be available, so I am still blocking and not *async* at all.

If I use non-blocking IO like Mio or *unsafe* `epoll`, do I still need `async` / `await`? If not, in what cases should I use `async` / `await`?

Comment: just code directly in byte if you think like that, don't even need an assembler. This kind of question is bad by nature on SO.

Comment: @Shepmaster it is not the same question, I want to know if `async / await` is still needed if I use non-blocking IO.

Comment: @Stargateur, If you think using Mio or libuv is like coding in byte, then this question is bad. The question is not about using low level techniques, it is that I want to know whether `async` is still necessary if I use non-blocking IO.

Comment: @Shepmaster, I am new to Rust, I may be wrong, that's why I post the question, and I hope someone can elaborate on the topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I use non-blocking IO like Mio or *unsafe* `epoll`, do I still need `async` / `await`?

**No**, *you* don't need `async` / `await`: you have code that does what you want, you are happy with it, and it doesn't use `async` / `await`. There's no apparent reason for you to change your code. You state this in multiple ways:

> Mio works the way I understand

> [Mio] is familiar to me.

> I can easily use this kind of API

The same style of question could be asked about functions. Functions aren't strictly needed because we could copy-paste code everywhere it's used. The code does what someone wants, someone is happy with it, and it doesn't make use of functions. There's no apparent reason for this developer to change their code.

---

**Yes** — in general, most Rust developers will use `async` / `await` when they are trying to write asynchronous code (and maybe even when they shouldn't). These keywords are mostly syntax sugar for creating a [future](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/future/trait.Future.html). Futures have existed in the Rust ecosystem for a long time before the special syntax was introduced, so even the syntax isn't required. However, it does make creating futures simpler.

Futures are an abstraction of asynchronous work that are ultimately driven by an *executor*. One of the things that it's possible to put underneath the abstraction is an event-based IO library. The library notifies the executor that something has changed with one of the IO handles the library manages, which causes the executor to resume the future, which may realize that it's complete.

Mio is used by some of the most common futures-related crates like [tokio](https://crates.io/crates/tokio) or [async-std](https://crates.io/crates/async-std). The Mio documentation even suggests using it with futures:

> This is a low level library, if you are looking for something easier to get started with, see Tokio.

See also:

- [What is the purpose of async/await in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52835725/155423)

Comment: I was just trying to state my understanding, not to prove myself. Since the `async` / `await` APIs look neat, I was wondering if they can fit in non-blocking IO use cases. So a simple **Yes** or **No** will be much more useful than any metaphors.