# What are the semantics of the expression x.await?

Tags: rust, async-await

I am curious about how `.await` actually works in Rust. It doesn't seem to be part of the `Future` API, so I assume that it has to be some sort of compiler magic. How does `.await` work and what it can be applied to?

I understand how async construction works and how async functions are compiled using unstable generators; that is not my question. I am asking specifically about the `.await` magic member operator. That is, if we have an expression like

```
fut.await
```

What happens at this point and what constraints should `fut` satisfy for this expression to be valid?

Comment: Basically `async fn` is compiled to a state machine. See Tyler Mandry's blog posts [How Rust optimizes async/await I](https://tmandry.gitlab.io/blog/posts/optimizing-await-1/) and [II](https://tmandry.gitlab.io/blog/posts/optimizing-await-2/).

Comment: The syntax let think that it's a variable member, but actually, it's an equivalent of `await {expression}` in the other languages.

Comment: @Shepmaster apologies if my question is valid. I agree that it is a bit broad but it basically boils down to *what is the semantics of an expression `x.await`*. If you think it is not appropriate for SO, I will happily move my question elsewhere

Comment: `await` is a keyword. It's not a member. The expression needs to implement the `Future` trait from `std`, which is a lang item, i.e. the compiler nows about it. Further details can be found in the [language reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/await-expr.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.await` is [a keyword](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.await.html), thus asking how it is defined is equivalent to asking how `if` or `match` are defined. The true answer is an unsatisfying one: look at [the code of the Rust compiler](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.39.0/src/librustc/hir/lowering/expr.rs#L503-L655).

The [async/await RFC](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2394-async_await.html) describes it as:

> ### The `await!` compiler built-in
>
> A builtin called `await!` is added to the compiler. `await!` can be used to
>   "pause" the computation of the future, yielding control back to the caller.
>   `await!` takes any expression which implements `IntoFuture`, and evaluates to a
>   value of the item type that that future has.
>
> ```rust
> // future: impl Future<Output = usize>
> let n = await!(future);
> ```
>
> The expansion of await repeatedly calls `poll` on the future it receives,
>   yielding control of the function when it returns `Poll::Pending` and
>   eventually evaluating to the item value when it returns `Poll::Ready`.
>
> `await!` can only be used inside of an async function, closure, or block.
>   Using it outside of that context is an error.
>
> (`await!` is a compiler built-in to leave space for deciding its exact syntax
>   later. See more information in the unresolved questions section.)

> ### The expansion of await
>
> The `await!` builtin expands roughly to this:
>
> ```rust
> let mut future = IntoFuture::into_future($expression);
> let mut pin = unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(&mut future) };
> loop {
>     match Future::poll(Pin::borrow(&mut pin), &mut ctx) {
>           Poll::Ready(item) => break item,
>           Poll::Pending     => yield,
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This is not a literal expansion, because the `yield` concept cannot be
>   expressed in the surface syntax within `async` functions. This is why `await!`
>   is a compiler builtin instead of an actual macro.

Note that the syntax `await!(expression)` was [changed](https://boats.gitlab.io/blog/post/await-decision/) to `expression.await` before stabilization.

> Does the compiler have magical knowledge of the `Future` trait

Yes. [`Future` is a language item](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.39.0/src/libcore/future/future.rs#L30).

> can `x` be anything that implements `IntoFuture` or is it more complicated?

There isn't actually an `IntoFuture` in the standard library; I assume that the level of indirection wasn't needed during implementation. `.await` only works with types implementing `Future`.

See also:

- [What is the purpose of async/await in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52835725/155423)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. There is just one piece of the puzzle remaining for me: the validity of the `.await` keyword used on an object `x`. Does the compiler have magical knowledge of the `Future` trait and can `x` be anything that implements `IntoFuture` or is it more complicated? Also, since you seem quite knowledgeable about the compiler, would you be so kind to point me to where I should look in the compiler code?