# Why do I get "expected type Future" error using match statement on Result?

Tags: asynchronous, struct, rust, match, crate

I'm trying to use a function in an external crate, it is supposed to return a `Result<T, E>` struct as implied by the function's signature:

```
pub async fn market_metrics(symbols: &[String]) -> Result<Vec<market_metrics::Item>, ApiError>
```

I'm trying to unpack the `Result<T, E>` with a `match` statement as instructed in Rust's documentation, but I am getting this error for some reason:

```
use tastyworks::market_metrics;

fn main() {
    let symbols = &[String::from("AAPL")];
    let m = market_metrics(symbols);
    match m {
        Ok(v) => v,
        Err(e) => panic!(e),
    }
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:7:9
   |
7  |         Ok(v) => v,
   |         ^^^^^ expected opaque type, found enum `std::result::Result`
   | 
  ::: /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tastyworks-0.13.0/src/lib.rs:79:52
   |
79 | pub async fn market_metrics(symbols: &[String]) -> Result<Vec<market_metrics::Item>, ApiError> {
   |                                                    ------------------------------------------- the `Output` of this `async fn`'s expected opaque type
   |
   = note: expected opaque type `impl std::future::Future`
                     found enum `std::result::Result<_, _>`
```

The dependency in Cargo.toml to use this crate is:
`tastyworks = "0.13"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you are trying to use is an `async` so you need to spawn an async task for it or run it in an async context. You need [`tokio`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.3.0/tokio/index.html) (or another async backend) for it:

```rust
use tastyworks::market_metrics;
use tokio;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let symbols = &[String::from("AAPL")];
    let m = market_metrics(symbols).await;
    match m {
        Ok(v) => v,
        Err(e) => panic!(e),
    }
}
```

Check some interesting [related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52835926/1695172)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I'll more about async, meanwhile I tried to run your code and im getting this `failed to resolve: could not find main in tokio

could not find main in tokio rustc(E0433)
main.rs(4, 10): could not find `main` in tokio and main function is not allowed to be async`

`main function is not allowed to be async rustc(E0752)
main.rs(5, 1): main function is not allowed to be async`

Comment: @orie, you probably miss the `tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }` in your tokio cargo entry.

Comment: that helped but now it produces a tokio-related issue `thread 'main' panicked at 'not currently running on a Tokio 0.2.x runtime.', /Users/or/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-0.2.25/src/runtime/handle.rs:118:28`

Comment: That means you have to use `tokio = { version = "0.2" }` too, since multiple major versions of Tokio can't be used together.

Comment: Adding to this: pulling in `tokio` with `features = ["full"]` probably gives you a bunch of functionality that neither you nor the dependency require. You might get away with `features = ["macros", "rt-core"]` or `features = ["macros", "rt-threaded"]`, depending on whether you want to use the single- or multi-threaded runtime.

Comment: changing to `tokio = { version = "0.2", features = ["full"] }` worked, that you all for the support!