# Chaining futures to an Option future

Tags: rust

```
extern crate futures; // 0.1.25

use futures::Future;

fn another_future(a: u8)  -> impl Future<Item=u8, Error=()> {
    println!("a is {}", a);
    futures::future::ok(a)
}

fn example() -> impl Future<Item=(), Error=()> {
    futures::future::ok(Some(127))
    .and_then(|opt| {
        if opt.is_some() {
        match opt {
            Some(n) => {
                another_future(n).and_then(|n| {
                    Ok(())
                })
            },
            None => {
                // i really don't want to call another
                // what to put in this branch to make the type check?
            },
        }
    })
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=05e3e51eada789c083663d6767ef3390)

I need to sort of conditionally apply `and_then`. In the example, the future resolves to and `Option`, and the result is passed to the next future by `and_then` only if it's not a `None`. But doing so leaves match arms with incompatible types.

One workaround is to not use `Option` and return errors instead of `None`. I wonder if there are more idiomatic alternatives.

Comment: The code you have provided is not syntactically valid. Presumably, you aren't  asking about that, so please ensure the code you are providing has the error that you are asking about.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How do I conditionally return different types of futures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51885745/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.