# Conditionally chaining a Rust future based on initial future result?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

If I've got some futures that I'm chaining together, how can I make the second chained future conditional on the result of the first future?

For a contrived example, I've got something like:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio_core;

use futures::{future, Future};
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;

fn add_one(x: i64) -> impl Future<Item = i64, Error = ()> {
    future::ok(x).map(|x| x + 1)
}

fn double(x: i64) -> impl Future<Item = i64, Error = ()> {
    future::ok(x).map(|x| x * 2)
}

fn add_one_then_double(x: i64) -> impl Future<Item = i64, Error = ()> {
    future::ok(x).and_then(add_one).and_then(double)
}

fn main() {
    let mut reactor = Core::new().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", reactor.run(add_one_then_double(10)).unwrap());
}
```

How can I then change the `add_one_then_double` future to be conditional on the result of the `add_one` future, e.g.:

```
fn add_one_then_double_if_positive(x: i64) -> impl Future<Item = i64, Error = ()> {
    future::ok(x).and_then(add_one).map(|v| {
        if v >= 0 {
            // chain the `double` future
        } else {
            // return `v` as the result
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How do I conditionally return different types of futures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51885745/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster That other question is only part of the answer.  The focus here is how to conditionally chain a future in one branch, but not in the other.  So as second piece of the answer, we need to use `future::ok()` to pass the value through unchanged.

Comment: @SvenMarnach but OP already knows how to use `future::ok`, as evidenced by the usage of it provided in the code.

Comment: @Shepmaster The rest of the question suggests otherwise.

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm happy to leave that in your hands. The questioned you linked gets me a bit closer to an answer (though I didn't find it through searching, as I was just looking for ways of conditionally chaining, rather than a solution that involved new futures).

Sven's answer is also helpful, and closer to the answer I might end up with.

The actual issue turns out to be more complicated than I'd thought, but will see if I can get anything working with `Either` first.

Comment: @Shepmaster sorry, hit return too early on that comment. I didn't initially realise what `and_then` returned, I thought it returned the original future, rather than a new one.

I'm working with a type from a 3rd party crate that is both impl `Future` and some other things, so returning a new future from `and_then` doesn't work, as it lacks the other traits the original future did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to chain another future, you need to use the `and_then()` future combinator, not `map()`.  This combinator expects another future as return value, so *both* branches of your `if` statement need to yield a future.  In the first branch, you want to chain `double(v)`, which already is a future.  In the second branch you want pass on the value unchanged, so you need to turn it into a future that immediately resolves to `v` using `future::ok()`.  Since `double(v)` and `future::ok(v)` have different types, you need to either use `future::Either`, or box the futures.  Here is one option:

```
fn add_one_then_double(x: i64) -> impl Future<Item=i64, Error=()> {
    future::ok(x)
        .and_then(add_one)
        .and_then(|v| {
            if v >= 0 {
                future::Either::A(double(v))
            } else {
                future::Either::B(future::ok(v))
            }
        })
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=b59f24728233ab87e16ea856bddc6b2c)