# Is there a way to continue within a futures for_each stream?

Tags: rust, future

I am doing a `for_each` loop over a stream of futures received via a `mspc::Receiver`

```
rx.for_each(move |trade| {
    if something_true {
        continue;
    }

    // down here I have computation logic which returns a future
});
```

I would like to do something like the logic above.

Of course, I could just do an if/else statement but both branches have to return the same type of future, which is hard for me to do as the future I generate in my computation logic is a long chain of messy futures. Which got me thinking if there is actually a simple way of approaching this, like a continue or some sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's solve the two issues separately. First, the easiest: if your chain of futures inside `for_each()` is not homogeneous (they rarely will be), consider returning a boxed future (i.e. `Box<dyn Future<Item = _, Error = _>>`). You may need to typecast the closure return to that, as the compiler will sometimes not get what you are trying to do.

Now, for the "continue if condition" - this typically means you're filtering out certain elements of the stream, which indicates that the better function to call may include `filter()` or an intermediate state - i.e. returning a future whose item type is `Option<_>`, and then filtering based on that in the next member of the chain.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. `continue` is syntax that is only accepted by the core Rust language and crates cannot make use of it.

You could instead return early:

```
rx.for_each(move |trade| {
    if true {
        return future::ok(());
    }

    future::ok(())
});
```

> both branches have to return the same type of future

Use `Either` or a boxed trait object

```
rx.for_each(move |trade| {
    if true {
        return Either::A(future::ok(()));
    }

    Either::B(future::lazy(|| future::ok(())))
});
```

See also:

- [How do I conditionally return different types of futures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51885745/155423)

I'd probably move the condition to the stream such that the `for_each` never sees it:

```
rx.filter(|trade| true)
    .for_each(move |trade| future::ok(()));
```