# Replace values in a string using flat_map

Tags: rust, iterator

I'm trying to write a simple function to escape HTML text (yes I know there are crates). Something like this:

```
fn escape(s: &str) -> String {
    s.chars().flat_map(|c| {
        match c {
            '<' => ['&', 'l', 't'].iter(),
            '>' => ['&', 'g', 't'].iter(),
            '"' => ['&', 'q', 'u', 'o', 't'].iter(),
            '\'' => ['&', 'a', 'p', 'o', 's'].iter(),
            '&' => ['&', 'a', 'm', 'p'].iter(),
            c => std::iter::once(c),
        }
    }).collect()
}
```

But it doesn't work, because the return types are different for the different arms:

```
expected struct `std::slice::Iter`, found struct `std::iter::Once`
```

I've tried many many things, but everything I try has some small problem:

- You can't do `"&lt".chars()` and `c.chars()` because `char` doesn't implement `chars()`.
- You can't do `[c].iter()` because `c` is on the stack and `iter()` only keeps a reference to it - I couldn't work out how to move stuff into the iterator (I guess you probably can't).

Is there some sensible solution (that doesn't involve `.to_string()`).

Comment: There's always the simple solution of using a good old `for` loop  and `push` and `push_str`... It looks cleaner to me than abusing `iter` and `flat_map`

Comment: That is a good point! Still, I'll leave the question open because I feel like you *should* be able to do this somehow.

Comment: why not just `[c].iter()` ?

Comment: @Stargateur: Read the question

Comment: @Stargateur who would own `c`? `iter()` just uses references, the other ones are fine because they are constants.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Conditionally iterate over one of several possible iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29760668/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Re abusing `flat_map` - check the [str::escape_default](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.escape_default) source for example -> `FlatMap`.

Comment: @zrzka You're right.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b727eda5c09c1eda329f873cd625a281

Comment: Some copy must be involved since the function is `fn(&str) -> String`