# How do I conditionally return different types of streams?

Tags: rust, stream

I have a function that makes paginated requests by querying the endpoint to count the number of pages, and then creates a stream of requests for each page that can be buffered however the client code wants.

Minimal example using [this post](https://gendignoux.com/blog/2021/04/01/rust-async-streams-futures-part1.html) for reference

```rust
use futures::{stream::*, *}; // 0.3.18
use lazy_static::lazy_static; // 1.4.0
use rand::distributions::{Distribution, Uniform}; // 0.8.4
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time::{sleep, Instant}; // 1.14.0

lazy_static! {
    static ref START_TIME: Instant = Instant::now();
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    println!("First 10 pages:\n{:?}", collect_pages_buffered(10, 2).await);
}

async fn collect_pages_buffered(
    page_count: usize,
    buff_factor: usize,
) -> Result<Vec<usize>, String> {
    stream_pages_buffered(page_count, buff_factor)
        .try_collect()
        .await
}

fn stream_pages_buffered(
    page_count: usize,
    buff_factor: usize,
) -> impl Stream<Item = Result<usize, String>> {
    stream_pages(page_count).buffered(buff_factor)
}

fn stream_pages(
    page_count: usize,
) -> impl Stream<Item = impl Future<Output = Result<usize, String>>> {
    let count_request = count_pages(page_count);
    stream::once(count_request).then(|result| match result {
        Ok(count) => get_pages_futures(count),
        Err(err) => stream::once(async { Err(err) }), // ERROR
    })
}

fn get_pages_futures(
    count: usize,
) -> impl Stream<Item = impl Future<Output = Result<usize, String>>> {
    stream::iter(0..(count - 1)).map(|i| get_page(i))
}

async fn count_pages(count: usize) -> Result<usize, String> {
    let millis = Uniform::from(0..10).sample(&mut rand::thread_rng());
    sleep(Duration::from_millis(millis)).await;
    println!(
        "[{}] # count_pages completed",
        START_TIME.elapsed().as_millis()
    );
    Ok(count)
}

async fn get_page(i: usize) -> Result<usize, String> {
    let millis = Uniform::from(0..10).sample(&mut rand::thread_rng());
    println!(
        "[{}] # get_page({}) will complete in {} ms",
        START_TIME.elapsed().as_millis(),
        i,
        millis
    );

    sleep(Duration::from_millis(millis)).await;
    println!(
        "[{}] # get_page({}) completed",
        START_TIME.elapsed().as_millis(),
        i
    );
    Ok(i)
}
```

On the branch where I handle if the page count request failed, the compiler gives me the error:

```
error[E0308]: `match` arms have incompatible types
  --> src/main.rs:40:21
   |
38 |       stream::once(count_request).then(|result| match result {
   |  _______________________________________________-
39 | |         Ok(count) => get_pages_futures(count),
   | |                      ------------------------ this is found to be of type `impl futures::Stream`
40 | |         Err(err) => stream::once(async { Err(err) }),
   | |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected opaque type, found struct `futures::stream::Once`
41 | |     })
   | |_____- `match` arms have incompatible types
   |
   = note: expected type `impl futures::Stream`
            found struct `futures::stream::Once<impl futures::Future>`
```

While the bottom branch is returning a concrete implementation of `Stream` (`stream::Once`), it has to be the same implementation as the `Ok` branch, but that can't be known since it's opaque.

If I try to wrap the `Err` branch in a function that returns `impl Stream` it still fails but now with

```
expected opaque type, found a different opaque type
```

because the `impl Stream` returned by each branch is not guaranteed to be the same.

How is one supposed to conditionally return different types of streams?  Is it even possible?  Should I instead always specify which concrete stream type I'm returning and then force each branch into the same type?

---

#### From "duplicate questions"

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29760740/2340690) suggests that using `.boxed()` will also work on streams but it doesn't seem to in this case.

```
error[E0308]: `match` arms have incompatible types
  --> src/main.rs:41:21
   |
39 |       stream::once(count_request).then(|result| match result {
   |  _______________________________________________-
40 | |         Ok(count) => get_pages_futures(count).boxed(),
   | |                      -------------------------------- this is found to be of type `Pin<Box<dyn futures::Stream<Item = impl futures::Future> + std::marker::Send>>`
41 | |         Err(err) => stream::once(async { Err(err) }).boxed(),
   | |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected opaque type, found enum `Result`
42 | |     })
   | |_____- `match` arms have incompatible types
   |
   = note: expected type `Pin<Box<dyn futures::Stream<Item = impl futures::Future> + std::marker::Send>>`
            found struct `Pin<Box<dyn futures::Stream<Item = Result<_, String>> + std::marker::Send>>`
```

This seems more promising.  It looks like my `Error` branch isn't a Stream of a single Future and is instead the result directly.

Using `Either` also doesn't seem to work.  Using `left_stream` and `right_stream` floods out errors.  Currently trying to reduce the number of errors by changing other types around it.

Comment: use enumeration

Comment: As linked in the duplicates, use a boxed trait object or an enum (such as the existing `Either`)

Comment: Practically, you could also do `count_pages(page_count).await?` and change the return type of `stream_pages`

Comment: @Shepmaster I'd like to keep the type signature as simple as possible and not `Future<Result<Stream<Future<Result<A>>>>>`.  If that's the only way that's the only way.  But all the suggested duplicate questions seem to imply that I was missing something and it is possible.

Comment: Why a stream of futures in the first place?

Comment: You have two dimensions that need to align: the type of the _stream_ and the type of the _item in the stream_. Boxing both (and probably using `Either`) [solves it](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=44252e22e74dd61114f6b8b61a588aea)

Comment: @Shepmaster Boxing both the future and the stream does work, thank you!  I noticed you also added more `async` uses.  Why were those necessary? I wanted to return a stream of Futures because buffering can only be done on a stream of Futures and I wanted to put that off until the last possible moment. (Instead of calling `buffered` and knowing the `buff_factor` on every stream created).