# trait with functions that return an iterator

Tags: iterator, rust, traits

I'm trying to build a trait with functions that return an iterator.

My simple example looks like this:

```
pub trait TraitA {
    fn things(&self) -> Iterator<Item=&u8>;
}

fn foo<A: TraitA>(a: &A) {
    for x in a.things() { }
}
```

Which does not work because the Iterator size type is not known at compile time.

Comment: If using an associated type like suggested in the answers below isn't suitable (it may not be), then you can return a `Box<Iterator<Item=&u8>>` instead. But this will require a heap allocation!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rust's libstd has one implementation of this, the trait `IntoIterator`.

```
/// Conversion into an `Iterator`
pub trait IntoIterator {
    /// The type of the elements being iterated
    type Item;

    /// A container for iterating over elements of type `Item`
    type IntoIter: Iterator<Item=Self::Item>;

    /// Consumes `Self` and returns an iterator over it
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter;
}
```

The trait has this peculiar by-value (`self`) formulation exactly to be able to express both “into iterator” and “borrow iterator” semantics.

Demonstrated by HashMap's `IntoIterator` implementations. (They use the hashmap's iterator structs `Iter` and `IntoIter`.)  What's interesting here is that the trait is implemented for the type `&HashMap<K, V, S>` to express the “borrow iterator”.

```
impl<'a, K, V, S> IntoIterator for &'a HashMap<K, V, S>
    where K: Eq + Hash, S: HashState
{
    type Item = (&'a K, &'a V);
    type IntoIter = Iter<'a, K, V>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Iter<'a, K, V> {
        self.iter()
    }
}

impl<K, V, S> IntoIterator for HashMap<K, V, S>
    where K: Eq + Hash, S: HashState
{
    type Item = (K, V);
    type IntoIter = IntoIter<K, V>;

    /// Creates a consuming iterator, that is, one that moves each key-value
    /// pair out of the map in arbitrary order. The map cannot be used after
    /// calling this.
    fn into_iter(self) -> IntoIter<K, V> {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535289/correct-way-to-return-an-iterator), I thought that the best way to do it would be to define the Iterator as a trait type, like so:

```
pub trait TraitA<'a> {
    type I1: Iterator<Item=u8>;
    type I2: Iterator<Item=&'a u8>;

    fn iter_i1(&self) -> Self::I1;
    fn iter_i2(&self) -> Self::I2;
}

fn foo<'a, A: TraitA<'a>>(a: &A) {
    for x in a.iter_i1() { }
    for x in a.iter_i2() { }
}
```