# How to return the result of a call to filter_map

Tags: iterator, rust, stack-memory

Here I have a vector vec of (char, usize) pairs, and I want to write a function

```
fn take_lt(&'a vec, cutoff: usize) -> Iterator<'a, char>
```

which returns an iterator over the chars matching values less than cutoff.

1. Is there a way to do this without the overhead of allocating something to heap (ie boxing up a Fn environment or creating another vector)?
2. Is there a way to do this
   without having to explicitly write out the hideous associated return
   type?

After trying this many different ways (a couple of which compiled, but all of which involved heap allocation which I'd like to avoid), I came up with:

```
use std::iter::repeat;
use std::iter::FilterMap;
use std::iter::Zip;
use std::iter::Repeat;
use std::slice;

fn take_lt<'a>(vec: &'a[(char, usize)], cutoff: usize) -> FilterMap<Zip<slice::Iter<'a, (char, usize)>, Repeat<usize>>, &fn((&(char, usize), usize)) -> Option<char>> {
    fn cmp_fun((&(x, a), b): (&(char, usize), usize)) -> Option<char> {
        if a < b {
            Some(x)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
    vec.iter().zip(repeat(cutoff)).filter_map(&cmp_fun)
}
```

This is close, but I get:

```
src/lib.rs:15:47: 15:55 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&fn((&(char, usize), usize)) -> core::option::Option<char>`,
    found `&fn((&(char, usize), usize)) -> core::option::Option<char> {take_lt::cmp_fun}`
(expected fn pointer,
    found fn item) [E0308]
src/lib.rs:15     vec.iter().zip(repeat(cutoff)).filter_map(&cmp_fun)
                                                            ^~~~~~~~
```

A little googling suggests I try casting the function item to a function pointer, as in:

```
vec.iter().zip(repeat(cutoff)).filter_map(&(cmp_fun as fn((&(char, usize), usize)) -> Option<char>))
```

but that fails with:

```
src/lib.rs:15:49: 15:103 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
src/lib.rs:15     vec.iter().zip(repeat(cutoff)).filter_map(&(cmp_fun as fn((&(char, usize), usize)) -> Option<char>))
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/lib.rs:7:167: 16:2 note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 7:166...
src/lib.rs: 7 fn take_lt<'a>(vec: &'a[(char, usize)], cutoff: usize) -> FilterMap<Zip<slice::Iter<'a, (char, usize)>, Repeat<usize>>, &fn((&(char, usize), usize)) -> Option<char>> {
src/lib.rs: 8     fn cmp_fun((&(x, a), b): (&(char, usize), usize)) -> Option<char> {
src/lib.rs: 9         if a < b {
src/lib.rs:10             Some(x)
src/lib.rs:11         } else {
src/lib.rs:12             None
              ...
src/lib.rs:7:167: 16:2 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 7:166
src/lib.rs: 7 fn take_lt<'a>(vec: &'a[(char, usize)], cutoff: usize) -> FilterMap<Zip<slice::Iter<'a, (char, usize)>, Repeat<usize>>, &fn((&(char, usize), usize)) -> Option<char>> {
src/lib.rs: 8     fn cmp_fun((&(x, a), b): (&(char, usize), usize)) -> Option<char> {
src/lib.rs: 9         if a < b {
src/lib.rs:10             Some(x)
src/lib.rs:11         } else {
src/lib.rs:12             None
              ...
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535289/correct-way-to-return-an-iterator.

Answer (score 3):

You were close:

```
// type alias for the return type (optional, I just find it a bit
// optically easier to work with). I added:
// a 'a lifetime parameter that ties the return Iter lifetime to the 
// input slice
// a 'static lifetime for the function pointer
type RetTake<'a> = FilterMap<Zip<slice::Iter<'a, (char, usize)>, 
    Repeat<usize>>, &'static fn((&(char, usize), usize)) -> Option<char>>;

fn take_lt<'a>(vec: &'a[(char, usize)], cutoff: usize) -> RetTake {
    fn cmp_fun((&(x, a), b): (&(char, usize), usize)) -> Option<char> {
        if a < b {
            Some(x)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    // I think this explicit static binding 
    // used not to be necessary, but I now can't get rustc
    // to give the reference to the function pointer the static lifetime
    // it needs otherwise 
    static F: fn((&(char, usize), usize)) -> Option<char> = cmp_fun;
    vec.iter().zip(repeat(cutoff)).filter_map(&F)
}
```

as an alternative you can create your own struct implementing the iterator logic you need and returning that struct. For instance:

```
struct CutoffIterator<'a> {
    iter: slice::Iter<'a, (char, usize)>,
    cutoff: usize,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for CutoffIterator<'a> {
    type Item = char;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<char> {
        loop {
            match self.iter.next() {
                Some(&(x, a)) if a < self.cutoff => return Some(x),
                Some(&(_, a)) if a >= self.cutoff => continue,
                _ => return None
            }
        }
    }
}

fn take_lt2(vec: &[(char, usize)], cutoff: usize) -> CutoffIterator {
    CutoffIterator { iter: vec.iter(), cutoff: cutoff }
}
```

Comment: I've never seen that (static F...) before.  Could you point me to where I can find out more about it?

Comment: Also is there a way to avoid the .zip(repeat()) hack and just save the environment as part of the iterator directly?

Comment: @dspyz static variables are covered in the [const and static section in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/const-and-static.html). F is a static variable with a type of "pointer to function"

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the zip (repeat ()) hack?

Comment: @dspyz to hide away the long type (which is after all an implementation detail that clients of your code should not have to care about) you can embed it as the inner type in a struct and impl Iterator on your struct (forwarding the next and size_hint to the ones already implemented on the inner type)

Comment: @PaoloFalabella What if the closure copies the `cutoff` value? It's `Copy` so you may not need the `Repeat` trick.

Comment: @TiborBenke It's true the environment must implement Copy (or at least Clone), but the problem here is that there doesn't seem to be anywhere to store the environment.  FilterMap can only take things which are Sized, which means it can only take a ref (&Fn, but not Fn).  However, this difficulty is not inherent to the problem, but rather to Rust.  If closures each have a unique type, then there's no reason their environment can't be sized.  But for that to work, the return type needs to include the closure type as a template parameter to FilterMap.

Comment: Why can't Rust allow the return-type to be a trait rather than a fully-specified type (fn my_func(...) -> Iterator<usize>) so long as the compiler can infer the full return type?   Note this is different than using a trait object, because the compiler still knows what the full return-type is, it's just for ease of readability and also allows for using private types in the (unwritten) signature of public functions without having to create a wrapper struct.

Comment: @dspyz there has been a lot of thinking on how to do exactly that, but not yet possible. See https://aturon.github.io/blog/2015/09/28/impl-trait/ for instance

Answer (score 1):

Each function has a unique, distinct type, that is compatible with an `fn` type. This mirrors the fact that closures also have distinct types. This is what the compiler means by `found fn item`: it didn't find the `fn` type you specified in the return type, but rather the unique type of the `cmp_fun` function.

`fn` types are already pointers, so there's no need (at least in your situation) to take a reference to an `fn`; you can just take an `fn` directly. By doing this, the compiler will implicitly cast the function to the more general `fn` type.

```
fn take_lt<'a>(vec: &'a[(char, usize)], cutoff: usize) -> FilterMap<Zip<slice::Iter<'a, (char, usize)>, Repeat<usize>>, fn((&(char, usize), usize)) -> Option<char>> {
    fn cmp_fun((&(x, a), b): (&(char, usize), usize)) -> Option<char> {
        if a < b {
            Some(x)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
    vec.iter().zip(repeat(cutoff)).filter_map(cmp_fun)
}
```