# What's the most efficient way to reuse an iterator in Rust?

Tags: iterator, rust, move-semantics

I'd like to reuse an iterator I made, so as to avoid paying to recreate it from scratch. But iterators don't seem to be `clone`able and `collect` moves the iterator so I can't reuse it.

Here's more or less the equivalent of what I'm trying to do.

```
let my_iter = my_string.unwrap_or("A").chars().flat_map(|c|c.to_uppercase()).map(|c| Tag::from(c).unwrap() );
let my_struct = {
  one: my_iter.collect(),
  two: my_iter.map(|c|{(c,Vec::new())}).collect(),
  three: my_iter.filter_map(|c|if c.predicate(){Some(c)}else{None}).collect(),
  four: my_iter.map(|c|{(c,1.0/my_float)}).collect(),
  five: my_iter.map(|c|(c,arg_time.unwrap_or(time::now()))).collect(),
  //etc...
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Iterators in general are `Clone`-able if all their "pieces" are `Clone`-able. You have a couple of them in `my_iter` that are not: the anonymous closures (like the one in flat_map) and the [ToUppercase](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/char/struct.ToUppercase.html) struct returned by `to_uppercase`.

What you can do is:

1. rebuild the whole thing (as @ArtemGr suggests). You could use a macro to avoid repetition. A bit ugly but should work.
2. collect `my_iter` into a `Vec` before populating my_struct (since you seem to collect it anyway in there): `let my_iter: Vec<char> = my_string.unwrap_or("A").chars().flat_map(|c|c.to_uppercase()).map(|c| Tag::from(c).unwrap() ).collect();`
3. create your own custom iterator. Without your definitions of `my_string` (since you call `unwrap_or` on it I assume it's not a `String`) and `Tag` it's hard to help you more concretely with this.

Comment: A few years down the road, all of these parts have been made cloneable: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=57f68b06d81e4f798e90c0bb8d38beea

Answer (score 18):

You should profile before you optimize something, otherwise you might end up making things *both* slower and more complex than they need to.

The iterators in your example

```
let my_iter = my_string.unwrap_or("A").chars().flat_map(|c|c.to_uppercase()).map(|c| Tag::from(c).unwrap() );
```

are thin structures allocated on the stack. Cloning them isn't going to be much cheaper than building them from scratch.

Constructing an iterator with `.chars().flat_map(|c| c.to_uppercase())` takes only a single nanosecond when I [benchmark](https://gist.github.com/ArtemGr/a6b080c7bf8a65d1d65f) it.

According to the same benchmark, wrapping iterator creation in a closure takes more time than simply building the iterator in-place.

Cloning a `Vec` iterator is not much faster than building it in-place, both are practically instant.

```
test construction_only    ... bench:           1 ns/iter (+/- 0)
test inplace_construction ... bench:         249 ns/iter (+/- 20)
test closure              ... bench:         282 ns/iter (+/- 18)
test vec_inplace_iter     ... bench:           0 ns/iter (+/- 0)
test vec_clone_iter       ... bench:           0 ns/iter (+/- 0)
```

Answer (score 5):

You may use closure to get identical iterators:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct{
    one:Vec<char>,
    two:Vec<char>,
    three:String
}

fn main() {
    let my_string:String = "ABCD1234absd".into();
    let my_iter = || my_string.chars();
    let my_struct = MyStruct{
        one: my_iter().collect(),
        two: my_iter().filter(|x| x.is_numeric()).collect(),
        three: my_iter().filter(|x| x.is_lowercase()).collect()
    };
    println!("{:?}", my_struct);
}
```

See also this [Correct way to return an Iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289) question.

Also you may clone iterator (see @Paolo Falabella answer about iterators cloneability):

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; 
    let mut i = v.iter().skip(2);
    let mut j = i.clone();
    println!("{:?}", i.take(3).collect::<Vec<_>>());
    println!("{:?}", j.filter(|&x| x%2==0).collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

Unfortunately I can't tell which way is more effective