# How do you implement an Iterator whose successor depends on the index of the term?

Tags: iterator, rust

I'm trying to implement an Iterator that yields the sequence x^2, x^2+x, x^2+2x, x^2+3x... for a constant (at call time) argument x, in Rust.

As I understand it, all I have to work with at any point in the implementation is `self.curr` and `self.next`. It seems to me that the sequence depends on the index of the item in the sequence.

```
struct SquareMultiple {
    // generates the sequence j = i^2, i^2+i, i^2+2i, i^2+3i, ...,
    curr: i64,
    next: i64,
}

// Implement `Iterator` for `SquareMultiple`.
// The `Iterator` trait only requires a method to be defined for the `next`
// element.
impl Iterator for SquareMultiple {
    type Item = i64;

    // Here, we define the sequence using `.curr` and `.next`.
    // The return type is `Option<T>`:
    //     * When the `Iterator` is finished, `None` is returned.
    //     * Otherwise, the next value is wrapped in `Some` and returned.
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<I64> {

        // FIXME: What to do here?
        let new_next = self.curr + self.next;

        self.curr = self.next;
        self.next = new_next;

        // Since there's no endpoint to a SquareMultiple sequence, the
        // `Iterator` will never return `None`, and `Some` is always returned.
        Some(self.curr)
    }
}

// Returns a SquareMultiple sequence generator
fn squareseq() -> SquareMultiple {
    SquareMultiple { curr: 1, next: 2 }
}
```

I also considered overloading the struct with a `index` attribute, but that seems somehow like an abuse of this pattern.

What's the Rustic way to go about this?

Comment: Instead of `Index` trait, you should implement [`Iterator::nth`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.nth) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Rust 1.34

With [`iter::successors`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.successors.html) and [impl trait](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423), this can be greatly simplified:

```
fn square_multiple(x: i64) -> impl Iterator<Item = i64> {
    std::iter::successors(Some(x * x), move |v| Some(v + x))
}
```

## Previously

You can store whatever you want in a struct that implements `Iterator`. It seems the simplest to me to store the current value and the value to increment by.

```
struct SquareMultiple {
    curr: i64,
    inc: i64,
}

impl Iterator for SquareMultiple {
    type Item = i64;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<i64> {
        let val = self.curr;
        self.curr += self.inc;
        Some(val)
    }
}

impl SquareMultiple {
    fn new(x: i64) -> Self {
        SquareMultiple { curr: x * x, inc: x }
    }
}

fn main() {
    for i in SquareMultiple::new(5).take(10) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

It's probably worth documenting that the iterator goes forever and thus will either panic or wraparound when it exceeds 2^63.

I like this solution because it doesn't multiply at all. For some reason, my brain thinks that adding is "easier" than multiplying.

---

If you really need to use the index, use a [`RangeFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFrom.html) and [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) it:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 5;
    let clever = (0..).map(|i| x * (x + i));
    for i in clever.take(10) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

If you need a separate function and *maximum performance* (add appropriate sound effect), you can create a new type:

```
use std::ops::RangeFrom;

struct SquareMultiple {
    iter: RangeFrom<i64>,
    x: i64,
}

impl SquareMultiple {
    fn new(x: i64) -> Self {
        SquareMultiple {
            iter: (0..),
            x: x,
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for SquareMultiple {
    type Item = i64;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<i64> {
        self.iter.next().map(|i| self.x * (self.x + i))
    }
}

fn main() {
    for i in SquareMultiple::new(5).take(10) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another relatively simple variant using `from_fn` is missing here:

```
fn square_multiple(x: i64) -> impl Iterator<Item = i64> {
    let x2 = x * x;
    let mut v = -x;
    std::iter::from_fn(move || {
        v += x;
        Some(x2 + v)
    })
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=b0c592c66379c8ed34be6ff9c221a941)