# Infinite loop when implementing custom iterator in Rust

Tags: iterator, rust

I am trying to implement a list [zipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_(data_structure)). So far I have:

```
#[derive(RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct ListZipper {
    pub focus: Option<Tile>,
    pub left: VecDeque<Tile>,
    pub right: VecDeque<Tile>,
}

impl PartialEq for ListZipper {
    fn eq(&self, other: &ListZipper) -> bool {
        self.left == other.left && self.focus == other.focus && self.right == other.right
    }
}
```

I am now trying to implement an iterator

```
impl Iterator for ListZipper {
    type Item = Tile;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Tile> {
        self.left.iter().chain(self.focus.iter()).chain(self.right.iter()).next().map(|w| *w)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    }
}
```

In my head this makes sense. When iterating over `ListZipper`, I want to iterate over `left`, then `focus` and then `right`. So I chain those iterators and just return `next()`.

This works fine if all fields in `ListZipper` are empty. As soon as one is not empty iterating over `ListZipper` results in an infinite loop.

The problem is not the chain. If I replace that by e.g. `self.left.iter()`, and `left` is not empty, the problem is the same. Likewise for `focus` and `right`.

I tried printing all elements in the iterator and it appears to go through the `VecDeque` from front to back, and then gets stuck. I.e. `next()` does not advance the cursor when it reaches the back.

Why?

I realize I may not want `ListZipper` itself to be an iterator, but that is another discussion.

Comment: You do realize `next` is creating a whole new iterator every time it's called right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your iterator is lacking a crucial piece of state: *how far along in the iteration it is*. Every time you call `next`, it constructs another iterator completely from scratch and gets the first element.

Here's a reduced example:

```
struct ListZipper {
    focus: Option<u8>,
}

impl Iterator for ListZipper {
    type Item = u8;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.focus.iter().next().cloned()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let lz = ListZipper { focus: Some(42) };
    let head: Vec<_> = lz.take(5).collect();
    println!("{:?}", head); // [42, 42, 42, 42, 42]
}
```

> I realize I may not want `ListZipper` itself to be an iterator, but that is another discussion.

No, it's really not ^_^. You need to somehow mutate the thing being iterated on so that it can change and have different values for each subsequent call.

If you want to return a combination of existing iterators and iterator adapters, refer to [Correct way to return an Iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423) for instructions.

Otherwise, you need to somehow change `ListZipper` during the call to `next`:

```
impl Iterator for ListZipper {
    type Item = Tile;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if let Some(v) = self.left.pop_front() {
            return Some(v);
        }

        if let Some(v) = self.focus.take() {
            return Some(v);
        }

        if let Some(v) = self.right.pop_front() {
            return Some(v);
        }

        None
    }
}
```

More succinctly:

```
impl Iterator for ListZipper {
    type Item = Tile;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.left.pop_front()
            .or_else(|| self.focus.take())
            .or_else(|| self.right.pop_front())
    }
}
```

---

Note that your `PartialEq` implementation seems to be the same as the automatically-derived one...

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

type Tile = u8;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub struct ListZipper {
    pub focus: Option<Tile>,
    pub left: VecDeque<Tile>,
    pub right: VecDeque<Tile>,
}

impl Iterator for ListZipper {
    type Item = Tile;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.left.pop_front()
            .or_else(|| self.focus.take())
            .or_else(|| self.right.pop_front())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let lz = ListZipper {
        focus: Some(42),
        left: vec![1, 2, 3].into(),
        right: vec![97, 98, 99].into(),
    };

    let head: Vec<_> = lz.take(5).collect();

    println!("{:?}", head);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaborate answer. It's clear now. Thanks for the comment on `PartialEq` as well.