# Match arms that return iterators?

Tags: rust, matching, traits, trait-objects

I've got some code that attempts to run a match where each branch can return a different type, but **all of these types implement `Iterator<Item=usize>`**.

```
let found: Iterator<Item = usize> = match requirements {
    Requirements::A => MatchingAs { ainternals: [] },
    Requirements::B => MatchingBs { binternals: [] },
    Requirements::C => MatchingCs { cinternals: [] },
};

return found.any(|m| m == 1)
```

... where `MatchingAs`, `MatchingBs`, and `MatchingCs` all `impl` `std::iter::Iterator<Item = usize>`.

I'm hitting a wall with the fact that the `Iterator` isn't sized:

```
    | the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `std::iter::Iterator<Item=usize>`
```

Is there a good approach to have match arms return objects with a shared trait, and then rely (only) on the trait in processing the results?

Comment: Please explain why this is not a duplicate of [Correct way to return an Iterator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423)

Answer (score 6):

The first reflex when you want to return something that is not `Sized`, is to `Box` it (aka, put it on the heap, return a pointer):

```
let found: Box<Iterator<Item = usize>> = match requirements {
    Requirements::A => Box::new(MatchingAs { ainternals: [] }),
    Requirements::B => Box::new(MatchingBs { binternals: [] }),
    Requirements::C => Box::new(MatchingCs { cinternals: [] }),
};

found.any(|m| m == 1)
```

This is not sufficient, here, because now `match` will complain that you return different types: `Box<MatchingAs>`, `Box<MatchingBs>`, ...

However, `Box<Concrete>` can be cast to `Box<Trait>` whenever there is an `impl Trait for Concrete`, so:

```
let found = match requirements {
    Requirements::A => Box::new(MatchingAs { ainternals: [] }) as Box<Iterator<Item = usize>>,
    Requirements::B => Box::new(MatchingBs { binternals: [] }) as Box<Iterator<Item = usize>>,
    Requirements::C => Box::new(MatchingCs { cinternals: [] }) as Box<Iterator<Item = usize>>,
};

found.any(|m| m == 1)
```

---

There is, though, an allocation-less solution: use generics.

```
fn search<T: Iterator<Item = usize>>(t: T) -> bool {
    t.any(|m| m == 1)
}
```

and then apply that function to each branch of the `match`:

```
match requirements {
    Requirements::A => search(MatchingAs {ainternals: []}),
    Requirements::B => search(MatchingBs {binternals: []}),
    Requirements::C => search(MatchingCs {cinternals: []}),
}
```

The trade-off is that it's a bit closer to callback-hell, with a somewhat indirect flow.