# What return type should I use for an iterable expression?

Tags: rust

I have a function that returns something that I feel should be iterable, but so far I have been collecting it and returning it as a vector.

```
pub fn grid_coords() -> Vec<(i32, i32)> {
    (0..SIZE).flat_map(|y| (0..SIZE).map(move |x| (x, y))).collect()
}
```

I assume that this will iterate before returning, and then the code calling this will just have to iterate again.

I tried removing the `.collect()` and letting the compiler guide me and ended up with something looking like `FlatMap<Range<i32>, Map<Range<i32>, Fn>, Fn>`, is there a less ugly looking type I could use?

Comment: The code in this question uses a closure, which means that some of the solutions from [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/1600898) don't apply here - for example, it is impossible return the equivalent of a newtype embedding `str::Split<'a, char>` or a type alias. The answer to the other question also doesn't mention the possibility of implementing the iterator manually, which is probably the only reasonable thing to do for the OP here (until `impl Trait` stabilizes). Nominating for reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In current (stable) Rust the easiest way to return a "conceptual" iterator is to return a boxed trait object implementing `Iterator`:

```
pub fn grid_coords() -> Box<Iterator<Item=(i32, i32)>> {
    let real_iter = (0..SIZE).flat_map(|y| (0..SIZE).map(move |x| (x, y)));
    Box::new(real_iter)
}
```

Using a box effectively [erases the type](http://davekilian.com/cpp-type-erasure.html) of the concrete iterator object with the upside that the caller doesn't need to know about the fact that it's implemented using `flat_map`. If you later switch `grid_coords` to use a different iteration primitive, such as [`yield`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ops/trait.Generator.html) once it stabilizes, the signature the function will not change and you are guaranteed not to break its callers. You could even go one step further and completely hide the box from the caller:

```
pub struct GridCoordIter {
    inner: Box<Iterator<Item=(i32, i32)>>
}

impl Iterator for GridCoordIter {
    type Item = (i32, i32);
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<(i32, i32)> {
        self.inner.next()
    }
}

pub fn grid_coords() -> GridCoordIter {
    let real_iter = (0..SIZE).flat_map(|y| (0..SIZE).map(move |x| (x, y)));
    GridCoordIter { inner: Box::new(real_iter) }
}
```

The downside of the boxed return is that it requires a small heap allocation for each call to `grid_coords`, and that each call to `next()` goes through a vtable-style indirection, neither of which is optimized away by current Rust. Whether this is a problem in practice depends on your usage, but if `grid_coords()` is a very basic function that might be called millions of times, it is not to be dismissed.

It is possible to eliminate the allocation and the indirection by using a different implementation of `GridCoordIter`. Unfortunately it is not possible to make the `inner` field a `FlatMap` value and retain the current implementation of `grid_coords`. The inner `FlatMap` would need to refer to the function's type, and the types of closures used by `grid_coords` are anonymous. This can be worked around by rewriting closures as callable structs, but at that point the convenience of using `flat_map` and `map` in the first place is lost, and it is easier to just implement `GridCoordIter::next` with the required logic:

```
pub struct GridCoordIter {
    i: i32,
    j: i32,
}

impl Iterator for GridCoordIter {
    type Item = (i32, i32);

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<(i32, i32)> {
        if self.j == SIZE {
            return None;
        }
        let coord = (self.i, self.j);
        self.i += 1;
        if self.i == SIZE {
            self.i = 0;
            self.j += 1;
        }
        Some(coord)
    }
}

pub fn grid_coords() -> GridCoordIter {
    GridCoordIter { i: 0, j: 0 }
}
```

Achieving both efficiency and brevity requires the `impl Trait` feature from unstable Rust, as shown in [Francis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46509606/1600898). It allows the function to directly return a value of an anonymous type that the caller doesn't need to know anything about, except that it implements a particular trait.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the discussion of efficiency as with the current approach it is about half of my execution time.

Comment: @Kazetsukai You're welcome. And - ouch!

Answer (score 2):

If you're OK with using a nightly compiler, you can use the unstable [`impl Trait` syntax](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1522-conservative-impl-trait.md):

```
#![feature(conservative_impl_trait)]

pub fn grid_coords() -> impl Iterator<Item = (i32, i32)> {
    (0..SIZE).flat_map(|y| (0..SIZE).map(move |x| (x, y)))
}
```

Comment: for stable you can use a Trait object: `Box<Iterator<Item=(i32, u32)>>`