# the `map` method cannot be invoked on a Iterator<T> trait object

Tags: rust, traits

I am trying to implement generic Resilient Distributed Datasets (RDD) in Rust. I have a `RDD` trait:

```
pub trait RDD<I, O>: Serialize {
    fn compute<II, OI>(&self, iter: II, partition: &Partition, context: &TaskContext) -> OI
    where
        OI: Iterator<Item = O>,
        II: Iterator<Item = I>;
}
```

Then the `MapRDD` struct and it's implementation of the `RDD` trait:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct MapRDD<F, I, O>
where
    F: RDDFunc<(I), O>,
{
    closure: F,
    marker: PhantomData<(I, O)>,
}

impl<F, I, O> RDD<I, O> for MapRDD<F, I, O>
where
    F: RDDFunc<(I), O>,
{
    fn compute<II, OI>(&self, iter: II, partition: &Partition, context: &TaskContext) -> OI
    where
        OI: Iterator<Item = O>,
        II: Iterator<Item = I>,
    {
        return iter.map::<O, FnMut(I) -> O>(|x: I| -> O { self.closure.call((x)) });
    }
}
```

There may be some dedudant type hint. The code doesn't compile:

```
error: the `map` method cannot be invoked on a trait object
  --> src/rdd/transformations/map.rs:16:25
   |
16 |             return iter.map::<O, FnMut(I) -> O>(|x: I| -> O {
   |
```

Because there will be arbitrary combination of compute results, which is the `Iterator<O>` or `OI` be chained to form a workflow, I have to use generic here.

What's the reason for this error? Can't a trait object, which is the `iter` here, be consumed by its underlying struct function?

Comment: The error is about type hint `FnMut(I)->O` on line 16, not `iter`. `FnMut(I)->O` is a trait, but you use it as a type, so compiler treats it as trait object, but trait objects should always be behind a pointer, thus you have the error.

Comment: When you'll fix this error (just remove type annotation), you'll need https://stackoverflow.com/a/27535594/2731452 to return iterator properly.

Comment: Also, your code doesn't produce the error you posted. Providing [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) saves lots of time.

Comment: @red75prime Oh, thank you. Not realised it is a duplicate question. Closing it now.

Comment: @red75prime After I removed type annotation, it complains `expected type parameter, found 'struct std::iter::Map'` from the beginning of `iter.map` to the end of the expression. That should be why I use a annotation om the first place. Any thoughts?