# How do I form a slice from a HashSet?

Tags: rust, lifetime

A struct is defined as:

```
struct Node {
    set: HashSet<usize>,
    // other fields omitted
}
```

I **have to** implement a function for a trait (compatibility issues) which needs to return all elements in the set as a slice.

I am aware of something like the following function won't work:

```
impl Node {
    pub fn set_slice(&self) -> &[usize] {
        let elems: Vec<_> = self.set.iter().cloned().collect();
        &elems[..]
    }
}
```

The problem is:

```
error[E0597]: `elems` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:11:10
   |
11 |         &elems[..]
   |          ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
12 |     }
   |     - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 9:5...
  --> src/main.rs:9:5
   |
9  | /     pub fn set_slice(&self) -> &[usize] {
10 | |         let elems: Vec<_> = self.set.iter().cloned().collect();
11 | |         &elems[..]
12 | |     }
   | |_____^
```

I know this requirement may sound strange. Despite why I have to do this, is there any 'good' way to achieve this?

If it is possible, I want keep the `HashSet` container for a O(1) lookup, and I don't want to introduce new struct members in order to save memory.

Comment: There is likely an XY problem here. Consider showing more context around the use of that trait. Also keep in mind that [owning containers such as `Vec` can coerce to slices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/1233251).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, your requirements are 100% completely impossible in safe Rust.

A `HashSet` / `HashMap` do not have a contiguous collection of data, thus there's no way to get a slice from them.

---

If you can change things, then you have options.

You can "render a view" of the `HashSet` if you can store a `Vec` and the method is `&mut self`:

```
struct Node {
    set: HashSet<usize>,
    view: Vec<usize>,
    // other fields omitted
}

impl Node {
    pub fn set_slice(&mut self) -> &[usize] {
        self.view.clear();
        self.view.extend(self.set.iter().cloned());
        &self.view
    }
}
```

You could return a `Cow` which would be either borrowed or owned:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

impl Node {
    pub fn set_slice(&self) -> Cow<[usize]> {
        self.set.iter().cloned().collect::<Vec<_>>().into()
    }
}
```

You could [return an iterator over the values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423):

```
impl Node {
    pub fn set_slice<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a usize> + 'a {
        self.set.iter()
    }
}
```

There's *possibly* [a crate](https://crates.io/) that uses a tightly-packed `Vec` as its backing storage, which could then be exposed as a slice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will adding lifetime constraints to the temporary variable `elems` work?

Comment: @Yang no. I mean it when I say impossible. If you can't change the `HashSet` or the trait and won't add fields, there's no solution.

Comment: I am trying to use `Cow`, once I have `let cow = Cow::from(&slice[..])` or `let cow = Cow::from(vec) `, how can I get back `&slice[..]`. I have used `cow.borrow()`, but error `type annotations required: cannot resolve 'std::borrow::Cow<'_, [u32]>: std::borrow::Borrow<_>'` shown up

Comment: @Yang `&cow[..]` ?

Answer (score 0):

That is impossible in simple (basic) ways.

That's possible with `Box`, `mut static` but I recommend to modify your trait and return something like in following example:

You can use `AsRef<[T]>` instead of `&[usize]` in your trait. Or simply return an iterator.

```
struct Node {
    set: HashSet<usize>,
}

trait SetSlice {
    type Slice: AsRef<[usize]>;
    fn get_slice_cloned(&self) -> Self::Slice;
}

impl SetSlice for Node {
    type Slice = Vec<usize>;
    fn get_slice_cloned(&self) -> Self::Slice { self.set.iter().cloned().collect() }
}

// there we use auto-impl of Iterator trait
// and return the iter.
// NOTE: we cannot use auto-impl in trait methods.
impl Node {
    fn get_neat_iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &usize> { self.set.iter() }
}

fn need_slice(slice: &[usize]) {}

fn main() {
    let n = Node { set: Default::default(), };

    // as_ref
    let all = n.get_slice_cloned();
    need_slice(all.as_ref());

    // iter-way
    let all: Vec<_> = n.get_neat_iter().cloned().collect();
    need_slice(&all);
}
```

This is only two ways from many.