# Returning a Future of a Stream trait object

Tags: stream, rust, future, traits

I'm using the `futures = "0.1.21"` crate and I'm trying to write a function that returns a trait object that is a "`Future` of a `Stream` of `bool`s".  In the real program, I'm establishing a connection to a server that periodically streams the status of its operations.

## Futures

I've been able to return a "`Future` of a `bool`" trait object like so:

```
extern crate futures;
use futures::{future, Future};

fn future() -> Box<Future<Item = bool, Error = std::io::Error>> {
    Box::new(future::ok(true))
}

fn main() { future(); }
```

Now I'd like to return a "`Future` of a `Stream` of `bool`s", but if I try:

```
extern crate futures;
use futures::{future, stream, Future, Stream};

fn stream_future() -> Box<Future<Item = Stream<Item = bool, Error = std::io::Error>, Error = std::io::Error>> {
    Box::new(future::ok(stream::empty::<bool, std::io::Error>()))
}

fn main() { stream_future(); }
```

It fails to compile with:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<futures::FutureResult<futures::stream::Empty<bool, std::io::Error>, std::io::Error> as futures::Future>::Item == futures::Stream<Item=bool, Error=std::io::Error>`
 --> src/main.rs:5:5
  |
5 |     Box::new(future::ok(stream::empty::<bool, std::io::Error>()))
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `futures::stream::Empty`, found trait futures::Stream
  |
  = note: expected type `futures::stream::Empty<bool, std::io::Error>`
             found type `futures::Stream<Item=bool, Error=std::io::Error>`
  = note: required for the cast to the object type `futures::Future<Item=futures::Stream<Item=bool, Error=std::io::Error>, Error=std::io::Error>`
```

## Iterators

I run into a similar problem if I try to return a nested `Iterator`, eg:

```
fn iter2() -> Box<Iterator<Item = Iterator<Item = bool>>> {
    Box::new(vec![vec![true].into_iter()].into_iter())
}
```

Fails with:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<std::vec::IntoIter<std::vec::IntoIter<bool>> as std::iter::Iterator>::Item == std::iter::Iterator<Item=bool>`
 --> src/main.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     Box::new(vec![vec![true].into_iter()].into_iter())
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::vec::IntoIter`, found trait std::iter::Iterator
  |
  = note: expected type `std::vec::IntoIter<bool>`
             found type `std::iter::Iterator<Item=bool>`
  = note: required for the cast to the object type `std::iter::Iterator<Item=std::iter::Iterator<Item=bool>>`
```

## Other options?

I suspect that either it isn't possible to "nest" traits like this or I haven't been able to figure out the syntax.

If it's not possible, is there another design/pattern I should look into to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 4):

Your question greatly confuses me. You seem to understand that you need<sup>1</sup> to box the future, so why didn't you apply the *exact same logic* to the stream?

```
type BoxedStream = Box<Stream<Item = bool, Error = io::Error>>;

fn stream_future() -> Box<Future<Item = BoxedStream, Error = io::Error>> {
    let s: BoxedStream = Box::new(stream::empty());
    Box::new(future::ok(s))
}
```

See also:

- [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423)

---

<sup>1</sup> This isn't actually always needed in modern Rust. In certain locations, you can use `impl Trait` to return a value implementing a trait without boxing it:

```
fn stream_future() -> impl Future<Item = impl Stream<Item = bool, Error = io::Error>, Error = io::Error> {
    future::ok(stream::empty())
}
```