# rust E0308 cannot deduce type

Tags: generics, rust

I am trying to create an iterator that wraps another iterator with a given associated type and does some additional work. I'm using generic types because it's not pretty to write out the concrete type of the wrapped iterator. I've reduced the error to the following code.

```
trait Trait {
    fn doit(&self);
}

struct S1 {}
impl Trait for S1 {
    fn doit(&self) {}
}

fn create_s1() -> S1 {
    S1 {}
}

fn create<S>() -> S
where
    S: Trait,
{
    create_s1()
}

fn main() {
    let s = create::<S1>();
}
```

The error I get is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:18:5
   |
14 | fn create<S>() -> S
   |                   - expected `S` because of return type
...
18 |     create_s1()
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found struct `S1`
   |
   = note: expected type `S`
              found type `S1`
```

It seems clear to me that `create_s1()` returns type `S1` and that type `S1` implements `Trait`. Why can't the compiler figure out the type of `S`?

I'm using rustc 1.32.0-nightly (b3af09205 2018-12-04)

Comment: You are attempting to lie to the compiler. `create<S>()` means that the caller of `create` can pick whatever concrete type for `S` that they'd like, but your function is only capable of returning a specific concrete type.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation makes sense to me. I tried searching for this but somehow didn't find any of the things you linked. I was "abusing" generics to avoid writing an ugly-looking type (like `std::iter::Cycle<std::slice::Iter<'v, i32>>`). Are there shortcuts to avoid having to actually type that out? I haven't found any so far.

Comment: That's what the latter two duplicates are pointing you to, especially [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535289/what-is-the-correct-way-to-return-an-iterator-or-any-other-trait). TL;DR: `-> impl Iterator<Item = i32>` (or whatever).

Comment: You're right. I over-reduced my question. Rather than return it from a function, if I want to store it in a struct, I found that `Box<Iterator<Item = &'v u32> + 'v>` works, but impl Trait isn't allowed in that position, and I don't know if some other syntax exists to solve it.

Comment: You can always make your struct generic like `S<'v, T: Iterator<Item = &'v u32> + 'v>`, or if you don't want to use a generic and need to use the type in several places, you can shorten it with a type alias: `type MyType = std::iter::Cycle<std::slice::Iter<'v, i32>>;` and then simply use `MyType` everywhere.