# What would be the signature of a function returning a generic struct?

Tags: generics, struct, rust, syslog

I was going through the [`syslog`](https://docs.rs/syslog/4.0.1/syslog) crate, and from my function, I wanted to return a logger object which I believe is of a generic struct `syslog::Logger`. Most of the below piece is taken from the crate documentation except for the return part and unwrap().

```rust
extern crate syslog;
use syslog::{Facility, Error, Formatter3164};

pub fn get_logger() -> syslog::Logger{
    let formatter = Formatter3164 {
        facility: Facility::LOG_USER,
        hostname: None,
        process: "myprogram".into(),
        pid: 0,
    };
    syslog::unix(formatter).unwrap()
}
```

However I am seeing

```
pub fn get_logger() -> syslog::Logger{
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected 3 type arguments
```

The signature of `syslog::Logger` struct is

```rust
pub struct Logger<Backend: Write, T, Formatter: LogFormat<T>>
```

and  the signature of `syslog::unix` is

```rust
pub fn unix<U: Display, F: Clone+LogFormat<U>>(formatter: F) -> Result<Logger<LoggerBackend, U, F>> {
```

where `Display` is `std::fmt::Display` and `LogFormat` is a trait defined in `syslog` crate with the following definition.

```rust
pub trait LogFormat<T> {
  fn format<W: Write>(&self, w: &mut W, severity: Severity, message: T)   -> Result<()>;

  fn emerg<W: Write>(&mut self, w: &mut W, message: T)   -> Result<()> {
    self.format(w, Severity::LOG_EMERG, message)
  }

  fn alert<W: Write>(&mut self, w: &mut W, message: T)   -> Result<()> {
    self.format(w, Severity::LOG_ALERT, message)
  }

  fn crit<W: Write>(&mut self, w: &mut W, message: T)    -> Result<()> {
    self.format(w, Severity::LOG_CRIT, message)
  }

  fn err<W: Write>(&mut self, w: &mut W, message: T)     -> Result<()> {
    self.format(w, Severity::LOG_ERR, message)
  }

  fn warning<W: Write>(&mut self, w: &mut W, message: T) -> Result<()> {
    self.format(w, Severity::LOG_WARNING, message)
  }

  fn notice<W: Write>(&mut self, w: &mut W, message: T)  -> Result<()> {
    self.format(w, Severity::LOG_NOTICE, message)
  }

  fn info<W: Write>(&mut self, w: &mut W, message: T)    -> Result<()> {
    self.format(w, Severity::LOG_INFO, message)
  }

  fn debug<W: Write>(&mut self, w: &mut W, message: T)   -> Result<()> {
    self.format(w, Severity::LOG_DEBUG, message)
  }
}
```

This is a generic struct, so what would be the type's signature that I should return if I want to return a logger object from my function?

Comment: [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535289/what-is-the-correct-way-to-return-an-iterator-or-any-other-trait) is pretty similar and the "let the compiler guide" approach will get you pretty far, but you'll still have to decide what `T` is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only optional parameter here is `T`. This is the type of the message you want when you are logging. E.g. in the below example, the log message type is a `&str`:

```rust
let mut logger = get_logger();

logger.info("This is a log message");
```

You can either choose the type inside `get_logger`, and put it in its signature, or make `get_logger` generic, and have the call site decide. 
The first approach looks like this:

```rust
extern crate syslog;
use syslog::{Facility, Error, Formatter3164, LoggerBackend};

fn get_logger<'a>() -> syslog::Logger<LoggerBackend, &'a str, Formatter3164>{
    let formatter = Formatter3164 {
        facility: Facility::LOG_USER,
        hostname: None,
        process: "myprogram".into(),
        pid: 0,
    };
    syslog::unix(formatter).unwrap()
}

pub fn main(){
  let mut logger = get_logger();

  logger.info("This is a log message");
}
```

And the generic approach looks like this.

```rust
extern crate syslog;
use syslog::{Facility, Error, Formatter3164, LoggerBackend};

pub fn get_logger<T: std::fmt::Display>() -> syslog::Logger<LoggerBackend, T, Formatter3164>{
    let formatter = Formatter3164 {
        facility: Facility::LOG_USER,
        hostname: None,
        process: "myprogram".into(),
        pid: 0,
    };
    syslog::unix(formatter).unwrap()
}

pub fn main(){
  let mut logger = get_logger();

  logger.info("This is a log message");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That explains a lot of concept which I missed.