# How to eliminate "expected &T, found type parameter" error when delegating to HashMap iterator?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to build a small graph library in Rust. A `Graph` trait will be implemented by all graphs, and `HashGraph` is a specific example. `HashGraph` itself will be a lightweight wrapper around `HashMap`.

In particular, I want the `HashGraph` method `nodes` to return an iterator that delegates `next` to an underlying iterator obtained from `HashGraph#keys`.

Here's my code:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub trait Graph<'a, N: 'a> {
    type Nodes: Iterator<Item=&'a N>;

    fn nodes(&'a self) -> Self::Nodes;
}

struct HashGraph<N> {
    map: HashMap<N, ()>
}

impl<N> HashGraph<N> {
    pub fn new(map: HashMap<N, ()>) -> Self {
        HashGraph { map }
    }
}

impl<'a, N: 'a> Graph<'a, &'a N> for HashGraph<N> {
    type Nodes = NodeIterator<'a, &'a N>;

    fn nodes(&'a self) -> Self::Nodes {
        NodeIterator::new(self.map.keys())
    }
}

struct NodeIterator<'a, N> {
    nodes: std::collections::hash_map::Keys<'a, N, ()>
}

impl<'a, N> NodeIterator<'a, N> {
    pub fn new(nodes: std::collections::hash_map::Keys<'a, N, ()>) -> Self {
        NodeIterator { nodes: nodes }
    }
}

impl<'a, N> Iterator for NodeIterator<'a, N> {
    type Item = &'a N;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.nodes.next()
    }
}
```

I'm trying to [avoid Boxing iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58611896/) using [the technique described in the answers here](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/5yappn/confused_about_how_to_return_iterators_from/).

This code does not compile due to a single error:

```
   |
23 |         NodeIterator::new(self.map.keys())
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected &N, found type parameter
   |
   = note: expected type `std::collections::hash_map::Keys<'_, &N, _>`
              found type `std::collections::hash_map::Keys<'_, N, _>`
```

It appears that the `HashMap` keys iterator isn't returning the expected form of the item, but I'm really unclear how to fix this error. My goal with `NodeIterator` is to just pass on whatever the `HashMap` iterator returns for `next`.

`HashGraph` should own its keys (the ones in its `HashMap`). Once created, `HashGraph` will be read-only.

The use of `HashMap<N, ()>` is mainly to simplify the sample code. It will ultimately use `HashMap<N, HashMap<N, E>>` where `E` is an edge weight. Clients would take care of ensuring proper ownership in the `HashMap` they pass with, for example, reference counting.

How can I modify the sample to eliminate the error and successfully compile?

Comment: I changed `&N` to `N` in the `impl Graph` and it can compile: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dc2555c5b5666b4636268b60eb51f9f2) . I don't quite understand what's going on enough to post an answer, but it looks like youre using `&N` extraneously in that spot.

Comment: [diff in a Gist](https://gist.github.com/turbulencetoo/c0fd50d9f7fd851562562069bdb367ae) so its more clear what changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the code compiling, you only need to remove a couple of extra `&`s.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub trait Graph<'a, N: 'a> {
    type Nodes: Iterator<Item = &'a N>;

    fn nodes(&'a self) -> Self::Nodes;
}

struct HashGraph<N> {
    map: HashMap<N, ()>,
}

impl<N> HashGraph<N> {
    pub fn new(map: HashMap<N, ()>) -> Self {
        HashGraph { map }
    }
}

impl<'a, N: 'a> Graph<'a, N> for HashGraph<N> {
    //                   ^^^ this one
    type Nodes = NodeIterator<'a, N>;
    //                           ^^^ and this one

    fn nodes(&'a self) -> Self::Nodes {
        NodeIterator::new(self.map.keys())
    }
}

struct NodeIterator<'a, N> {
    nodes: std::collections::hash_map::Keys<'a, N, ()>,
}

impl<'a, N> NodeIterator<'a, N> {
    pub fn new(nodes: std::collections::hash_map::Keys<'a, N, ()>) -> Self {
        NodeIterator { nodes }
    }
}

impl<'a, N> Iterator for NodeIterator<'a, N> {
    type Item = &'a N;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.nodes.next()
    }
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=34f1a7ed8554ac34f755f40bb6403967)

The reasons for this come down to the signatures on the trait `Graph` and the struct `NodeIterator`. When fed `Keys<'a, N, ()>`, `NodeIterator::new` returns `NodeIterator<'a, N>`. However, for your implementation of `Graph` you want it to return something of type `Nodes`, which is the type `NodeIterator<'a, &'a N>`. Notice the extra `&'a`. Moreover, it needs to return an iterator whose items have type `&'a N`. Removing some of the `&'a`s makes everything consistent.

Another solution is to add an *extra* `&'a`.

```
impl<'a, N: 'a> Graph<'a, &'a N> for HashGraph<&'a N> {
    //                                         ^^^ right here
    type Nodes = NodeIterator<'a, &'a N>;

    fn nodes(&'a self) -> Self::Nodes {
        NodeIterator::new(self.map.keys())
    }
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bf4258052d51b6224c5b9c35f64e3c23)

That would mean that you're consistently using `&'a N` rather than `N` itself.

The key here is consistency, but you'll also want to think ahead to how you're going to use these types and traits. Do you want `HashGraph` to only have references to its keys or own them? If they're references, what actually owns them? If you use owned keys, are you going to need to move them around a lot?

One last thing. You're using `HashMap<N, ()>` but, depending on what exactly you're trying to do, `HashSet<N>` might be more idiomatic. The two are exactly the same under the hood, but `HashSet` has a different set of methods that may or may not be more useful for you.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I noticed that using the 2nd approach allows compilation, but then I can't call graph.nodes(). Ideas? I'll update my question with answers to your other questions.

Comment: @RichApodaca It would depend on the exact error. I didn't get any errors [in my attempt](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c9c44c252cb7f31000f4ad4b5c25ca5c).