# Eliminate lifetime parameter from a trait whose implementation wraps a HashMap?

Tags: rust

I'd like to wrap a few methods of `HashMap` such as `insert` and `keys`. This attempt compiles, and the tests pass:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;

pub trait Map<'a, N: 'a> {
    type ItemIterator: Iterator<Item=&'a N>;

    fn items(&'a self) -> Self::ItemIterator;
    fn insert(&mut self, item: N);
}

struct MyMap<N> {
    map: HashMap<N, ()>
}

impl<N: Eq + Hash> MyMap<N> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        MyMap { map: HashMap::new() }
    }
}

impl<'a, N: 'a + Eq + Hash> Map<'a, N> for MyMap<N> {
    type ItemIterator = std::collections::hash_map::Keys<'a, N, ()>;

    fn items(&'a self) -> Self::ItemIterator {
        self.map.keys()
    }

    fn insert(&mut self, item: N) {
        self.map.insert(item, ());
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[derive(Eq, Hash, PartialEq, Debug)]
    struct MyItem;

    #[test]
    fn test() {
        let mut map = MyMap::new();
        let item = MyItem { };

        map.insert(&item);

        let foo = map.items().collect::<Vec<_>>();

        for it_item in map.items() {
            assert_eq!(it_item, &&item);
        }

        assert_eq!(foo, vec![&&item]);
    }
}
```

I'd like to eliminate the need for the lifetime parameter in `Map` if possible, but so far haven't found a way. The problem seems to result from the definition of `std::collections::hash_map::Keys`, which requires a lifetime parameter.

Attempts to redefine the `Map` trait work until it becomes necessary to supply the lifetime parameter on `Keys`:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;

pub trait Map<N> {
    type ItemIterator: Iterator<Item=N>;

    fn items(&self) -> Self::ItemIterator;
    fn insert(&mut self, item: N);
}

struct MyMap<N> {
    map: HashMap<N, ()>
}

impl<N: Eq + Hash> MyMap<N> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        MyMap { map: HashMap::new() }
    }
}

// ERROR: "unconstrained lifetime parameter"
impl<'a, N> Map<N> for MyMap<N> {
    type ItemIterator = std::collections::hash_map::Keys<'a, N, ()>;
}
```

The compiler issues an error about an unconstrained lifetime parameter that I haven't been able to fix without re-introducing the lifetime into the `Map` trait.

The main goal of this experiment was to see how I could also eliminate `Box` from previous attempts. As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535289/what-is-the-correct-way-to-return-an-iterator-or-any-other-trait) explains, that's another way to return an iterator. So I'm not interested in that approach at the moment.

How can I set up `Map` and an implementation *without* introducing a lifetime parameter or using `Box`?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f65d3af82d3cab5a3a06357889255b83

Comment: @Stargateur - not so much the first link but the second one is helpful ("for &'a MyMap"). I can't seem to get it into a form I'm after, though. Implementing insert, I get "cannot borrow `self.map` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference".

Comment: the first link still explain to you why people run into this problem, if you read carefully you can see "However, it can yield borrowed values from something else.", this is exposed with my code example, while I show you the way, use an **other** structure to implement the iterator, this other structure will refer the lifetime. While I didn't use your "Map" trait because it's useless, I think you have understand the point. Your `Map` trait is not suitable/useful, first no one need it's custom map, secondly, you should just use `IntoIterator`. (or method like real hashmap)

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fd58489633acdfda94d1de174814afe6

Comment: I'm a bit confused... why are you trying to remove the lifetime parameter? What's wrong with your current code? Here's why I think it may be necessary: let's say you are writing a generic function `fn foo<N, M: Map<N>>(map: &M)`; you wouldn't know what lifetime `N` is valid for.

Comment: @Coder-256, I'm still not 100% clear on lifetimes. I've recently seen how it's possible to litter code with lifetimes and then remove (almost) all of them. I'd just like some confidence there's no simplification possible here. Your comment was helpful in that respect.

Comment: Glad I could help! I wrote an answer with more info. Did that address the rest of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to think about is that since `hash_map::Keys` has a generic lifetime parameter, it is probably necessary for some reason, so your trait to abstract over `Keys` will probably need it to.

In this case, in the definition of `Map`, you need some way to specify how long the `ItemIterator`'s `Item` lives. (The `Item` is `&'a N`).

This was your definition:

```rust
type ItemIterator: Iterator<Item=&'a N>
```

You are trying to say that for any struct that implements `Map`, the struct's associated `ItemIterator` must be an iterator of references; however, this constraint alone is useless without any further information: we also need to know how long the reference lives for (hence why `type ItemIterator: Iterator<Item=&N>` throws an error: it is missing this information, and it cannot currently be elided AFAIK).

So, you choose `'a` to name a generic lifetime that you guarantee each `&'a N` will be valid for. Now, in order to satisfy the borrow checker, prove that `&'a N` will be valid for `'a`, and establish some useful promises about `'a`, you specify that:

1. Any value for the reference `&self` given to `items()` must live at least as long as `'a`. This ensures that for each of the returned items (`&'a N`), the `&self` reference must still be valid in order for the item reference to remain valid, in other words, the items must outlive `self`. This invariant allows you to reference `&self` in the return value of `items()`. You have specified this with `fn items(&'a self)`. (Side note: `my_map.items()` is really shorthand for `MyMap::items(&my_map)`).
2. Each of the `N`s themselves must also remain valid for as long as `'a`. This is important if the objects contain any references that won't live forever (aka non-`'static` references); this ensures that all of the references that the item `N` contains live at least as long as `'a`. You have specified this with the constraint `N: 'a`.

So, to recap, the definition of `Map<'a, N>` requires that an implementors' `items()` function must return an `ItemIterator` of references that are valid for `'a` to items that are valid for `'a`. Now, your implementation:

```rust
impl<'a, N: 'a + Eq + Hash> Map<'a, N> for MyMap<N> { ... }
```

As you can see, the `'a` parameter is completely unconstrained, so you can use any `'a` with the methods from `Map` on an instance of `MyMap`, as long as `N` fulfills its constraints of `N: 'a + Eq + Hash`. `'a` should automatically become the longest lifetime for which both `N` and the map passed to `items()` are valid.

Anyway, what you're describing here is known as a streaming iterator, which has been a problem in years. For some relevant discussion, see the approved but currently unimplemented [RFC 1598](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1598) (but prepare to be overwhelmed).

Finally, as some people have commented, it's possible that your `Map` trait might be a bad design from the start since it may be better expressed as a combination of the built-in `IntoIterator<Item=&'a N>` and a separate trait for `insert()`. This would mean that the default iterator used in `for` loops, etc. would be the items iterator, which is inconsistent with the built-in `HashMap`, but I am not totally clear on the purpose of your trait so I think your design likely makes sense.