# Syntax issue function returns function not clear

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm getting confused by this. 
If the following works:

```
fn func_exit() -> bool {
    println!("hi");
    true
}

fn locate_func() -> fn() -> bool {
    func_exit
}
```

Why these following syntaxes throw error?

```
fn locate_func1<F: Fn() -> bool>() -> F {
     func_exit
}
fn locate_func2<F>() -> F where F:Fn() -> bool {
    func_exit
}
```

I'm new to Rust and the following error message is not clear to me:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:44:9
   |
43 |     fn locate_func1<F: Fn() -> bool>() -> F {
   |                     - this type parameter - expected `F` because of return type
44 |         func_exit
   |         ^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `F`, found fn item
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `F`
                     found fn item `fn() -> bool {func_exit}`
   = help: type parameters must be constrained to match other types
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:47:9
   |
46 |     fn locate_func2<F>() -> F where F:Fn() -> bool {
   |                     -       - expected `F` because of return type
   |                     |
   |                     this type parameter
47 |         func_exit
   |         ^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `F`, found fn item
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `F`
                     found fn item `fn() -> bool {func_exit}`
   = help: type parameters must be constrained to match other types
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters
```

Appreciate some help.
Thanks

Comment: Well the compiler expects it to be `fn` while you wrote `Fn`. Both exist in Rust, but are different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fn locate_func() -> fn() -> bool {
    func_exit
}
```

`locate_func` returns a pointer to a function returning bool (i.e. `fn() -> bool`).

```
fn locate_func1<F: Fn() -> bool>() -> F {
     func_exit
}
```

`locate_func1` means that the *caller* can specify any `F` satisfying the bounds `Fn() -> bool`, and it will return an `F`. But it is clearly not the case that `func_exit` is necessarily of the type specified by the caller.

`locate_func2` has the same problem, just with `where`-Notation.

What you probably want could be the following:

```
fn locate_func3() -> impl Fn() -> bool {
     func_exit
}
```

It says: `locate_func3` returns something that implements the bound `Fn() -> bool` (and `func_exit` does so, so it can be returned there).

Also note the difference between [`fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.fn.html) (function pointers) and [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html) ("something callable"):

Comment: Thanks for your response. So what I found that both of these two systaxes work: fn locate_func3() -> impl Fn() -> bool { func_exit } and fn locate_func3() -> fn() -> bool { func_exit }. But if I replace the F: Fn() -> bool in the other signature with F: impl Fn() -> bool even then it's not working: fn locate_func1<F: impl Fn() -> bool> () -> F { func_exit }. What goes wrong in here? Thanks.

Comment: The error: error: expected one of `!`, `(`, `,`, `=`, `>`, `?`, `for`, lifetime, or path, found keyword `impl`
  --> src/main.rs:20:20
   |
20 | fn locate_func1<F: impl Fn() -> bool> () -> F {
   |                    ^^^^ expected one of 9 possible tokens

error: aborting due to previous error

Comment: @Prana As soon as you have `F` in `locate_func1<F: ...>`, you allow the **caller** to specify `F`. But as soon you allow this, you will run into problems because `func_exit` would have to match the type **specified by the caller** (what should the caller meaningfully specify here?). What you instead want is that a caller can just call `locate_func` and get something that can be called. This is specified by e.g. returning `impl Fn()->bool`. As for the syntax error: `impl` is not allowed in trait bounds.

Comment: Another view is that `locate_func<F>` must work *for any* `F` provided by the caller, while `locate_func()->impl Fn...` says that *there exists* a type satisfying the bounds mentioned that is returned by the function.

Comment: Just one more query. If I have to write a function signature that returns a generic function, how should that be written? Like fn fname<F>() ->F. Or that cannot be written like this? Thanks

Comment: @Prana writing this means you basically have to return a function which you're given, so it's usually not useful. If you want to return a specific function (but don't want to give its details in the API) you need to return `impl Fn...`, if you want to return one of a variety of functions then you probably need to return a trait object or somesuch, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27535594/8182118 for explanation & various options.

Answer (score 1):

The error is weird, but... you can't just return a bounded value like this, because bounded types are decided by the caller, and it doesn't make sense for the caller to decide what the return type is *unless* that return type is a consequence of an input type (e.g. an identity function is a trivial example of this). Which is not the case here.

If you want to return something generic, you need either some sort of *trait object* (so e.g. box the function and return a Box) or an `impl` (which still has a concrete return value but hides it at the API level).

The latter is more efficient but only allows returning a single concrete type, the former is less efficient but lets you return e.g. different closures.