# How do I prevent impl Trait moved into function from being dropped while still borrowed?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'd like to define a trait `Holder` that can iterate some through the `items` method. I don't want to return a trait object from this method because I'd like to stick with static dispatch and stack allocation if possible. The system I have works fine, but fails in a sort of surprising situation.

Here's the code:

```rust
pub trait Holder<'a, N: 'a> {
    type Items: Iterator<Item=&'a N>;

    fn items(&'a self) -> Self::Items;
}

struct Impl<N> {
    items: Vec<N>
}

impl<'a, N: 'a> Holder<'a, N> for Impl<N> {
    type Items = std::slice::Iter<'a, N>;

    fn items(&'a self) -> Self::Items {
        self.items.iter()
    }
}

fn use_holder<'a, N: 'a>(holder: impl Holder<'a, N>) {
    // COMPILE ERROR
    for item in holder.items() {

    }
}
```

Here's the error:

```
error[E0309]: the parameter type `impl Holder<'a, N>` may not live long enough
  --> src/graph/test.rs:20:17
   |
19 | fn use_holder<'a, N: 'a>(holder: impl Holder<'a, N>) {
   |                                  ------------------ help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `impl Holder<'a, N> + 'a`
20 |     for item in holder.items() {
   |                 ^^^^^^
   |
note: ...so that the type `impl Holder<'a, N>` is not borrowed for too long
  --> src/graph/test.rs:20:17
   |
20 |     for item in holder.items() {
   |                 ^^^^^^

error[E0309]: the parameter type `impl Holder<'a, N>` may not live long enough
  --> src/graph/test.rs:20:24
   |
19 | fn use_holder<'a, N: 'a>(holder: impl Holder<'a, N>) {
   |                                  ------------------ help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `impl Holder<'a, N> + 'a`
20 |     for item in holder.items() {
   |                        ^^^^^
   |
note: ...so that the reference type `&'a impl Holder<'a, N>` does not outlive the data it points at
  --> src/graph/test.rs:20:24
   |
20 |     for item in holder.items() {
   |                        ^^^^^

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors; 4 warnings emitted

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0309`.
```

I follow the compiler's advice and add the explicit lifetime:

```rust
pub trait Holder<'a, N: 'a> {
    type Items: Iterator<Item=&'a N>;

    fn items(&'a self) -> Self::Items;
}

struct Impl<N> {
    items: Vec<N>
}

impl<'a, N: 'a> Holder<'a, N> for Impl<N> {
    type Items = std::slice::Iter<'a, N>;

    fn items(&'a self) -> Self::Items {
        self.items.iter()
    }
}

fn use_holder<'a, N: 'a>(holder: impl Holder<'a, N> + 'a) {
    for item in holder.items() {

    }
}
```

Which gives the error:

```
error[E0597]: `holder` does not live long enough
  --> src/graph/test.rs:20:17
   |
19 | fn use_holder<'a, N: 'a>(holder: impl Holder<'a, N> + 'a) {
   |               -- lifetime `'a` defined here
20 |     for item in holder.items() {
   |                 ^^^^^^--------
   |                 |
   |                 borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                 argument requires that `holder` is borrowed for `'a`
...
23 | }
   | - `holder` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535289/what-is-the-correct-way-to-return-an-iterator-or-any-other-trait) and several other tangentially related to this problem, but can't understand how to move forward.

Other than returning a trait object from `Hoder#items`, what are my options to get the loop in `use_hodler` working?

Comment: without concrete usecase it's hard to know what you want to do but there is some limitation about lifetime on trait, see GATs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually very difficult - lifetimes and associated types appears to be one of those weird corner cases in Rust that is not (yet) well supported. I'd be lying if I said I properly understood the reasons for the error, however I've managed to get this to work *for this specific example* using [Higher Ranked Trait Bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html).

You only need to change one line:

```rust
fn use_holder<N>(holder: impl for<'a> Holder<'a, N>) {
```

Note that the lifetime parameter has moved to the `for<'a>`. What this means is that the `holder` parameter implements `Holder<'a, N>` for every possible lifetime `'a`, rather than for a specific `'a` that lives at least as long as the function.

You'd need to use `for<'a> ...`  most of the places you use this trait, so it will become messy quite quickly. And higher ranked trait bounds is not a commonly used feature: It's pretty niche and has been elided for the most common cases, so it's not going to help with legibility or maintainability.

I'd recommend changing your architecture to avoid this construction if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks very much for this clear answer. It compiles and runs, but does seem to cut against the grain. I was also able to get the where version working, as described in the link.

Comment: Maybe one day, you'll be able to express this with GATs. It [currently works in nightly](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1f1edbb717774e898750ee7901de63c7), but it's still incomplete and subject to change.