# How do I return a boxed iterator that returns boxed iterators of f64?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to read a CSV file using the [CSV crate](https://docs.rs/csv/1.1.4/csv/index.html) and lazily cast all its cells to `f64`:

```rust
use csv::ReaderBuilder; // 1.1.4

fn get_df_iterator(path: &str) {
    // Build the CSV reader and iterate over each record casting to f64
    let rdr = ReaderBuilder::new()
        .delimiter(b'\t')
        .from_path(path)
        .unwrap();

    rdr.into_records().map(|record_result| {
        record_result
            .unwrap()
            .into_iter()
            .map(|cell: &str| cell.parse::<f64>().unwrap())
    })
}

fn main() {
    let m1 = get_df_iterator("df1.csv");
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bbf6f1070ea805d87bf053247117cf1f)

I've read that to return types with closures in stable Rust we can use `Box`es. I've tried with:

```
use csv::{Error, ReaderBuilder, StringRecord};

fn get_df_iterator_box(path: &str) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Box<dyn Iterator<Item = f64>>>> {
    // Build the CSV reader and iterate over each record.
    let rdr = ReaderBuilder::new()
        .delimiter(b'\t')
        .from_path(path)
        .unwrap();

    // Returns Box<Iterator<Item = f64>>
    let parse_str = |cell: &str| cell.parse::<f64>().unwrap();

    let parse_record = |record_result: Result<StringRecord, Error>| {
        Box::new(record_result.unwrap().into_iter().map(parse_str))
    };

    // Box<Iterator<Item = Box<Iterator<Item = f64>>>>
    Box::new(rdr.into_records().map(parse_record))
}

fn main() {
    let m1 = get_df_iterator_box("df1.csv");
}
```

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<[closure@src/main.rs:13:24: 15:6] as FnOnce<(std::result::Result<StringRecord, csv::Error>,)>>::Output == Box<(dyn Iterator<Item = f64> + 'static)>`
  --> src/main.rs:18:5
   |
11 |     let parse_str = |cell: &str| cell.parse::<f64>().unwrap();
   |                     ----------------------------------------- the expected closure
...
18 |     Box::new(rdr.into_records().map(parse_record))
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Map`, found trait object `dyn Iterator`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Box<Map<StringRecordIter<'_>, [closure@src/main.rs:11:21: 11:62]>>`
              found struct `Box<(dyn Iterator<Item = f64> + 'static)>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Iterator` for `Map<StringRecordsIntoIter<File>, [closure@src/main.rs:13:24: 15:6]>`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn Iterator<Item = Box<(dyn Iterator<Item = f64> + 'static)>>`
```

I don't understand what the problem is. It's supposed to return a `Box` which contains an iterator that returns `Box`es of iterators of `f64`. [Here there's another playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=918b0285926ca8e3ee28c3d53fcbbbce) with that update! If you want to replicate with the same file I'm using [here you can download it](https://drive.google.com/file/d/124fIO8lb4xOvXV8E5GBdjRBEmofiHW_R/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Note that boxed trait objects are not the _only_ possibility — [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423)

Comment: `Box::new(record_result.unwrap().into_iter().map(parse_str)) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item = f64>>`

Comment: Or, as @Shepmaster mentioned you could return `impl Iterator<Item = impl Iterator<Item = f64>>`

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the return type of the closure to tell Rust that you are returning a `dyn trait`:

```rust
let parse_record =
    |record_result: Result<StringRecord, Error>| -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = f64>> {
        Box::new(record_result.unwrap().into_iter().map(parse_str))
    };
```

An alternative method would be to explicitly cast within the closure:

```rust
let parse_record = |record_result: Result<StringRecord, Error>| {
    Box::new(record_result.unwrap().into_iter().map(parse_str)) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item = f64>>
};
```

You could instead return [`impl trait`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1522-conservative-impl-trait.md) instead of using dynamic dispatch and avoid this altogether:

```rust
fn get_iterator(path: &str) -> impl Iterator<Item = impl Iterator<Item = f64>> { ... }
```

*For more information about returning traits, see [What is the correct way to return an Iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535289/what-is-the-correct-way-to-return-an-iterator-or-any-other-trait)*

Comment: Cool! That worked! Thank you for all the explanation and references