# How do I get an enum as a string?

Tags: rust

I have an enum with many values and I'd like to write the name of one of its values to a stream:

```
enum Foo {
    Bar = 0x00,
    Baz = 0x01,
    Qux = 0x02,
    // ...
    Quux = 0xFF,
}
```

I can derive `Debug` and do

```
writer.write(format!("I am {:?}", Foo::Quux).as_bytes())
```

which will output e.g. `I am Quux`. That's fine, except that

- I want to do this for user-facing output, so `Debug` isn't appropriate
- It would be very helpful to get the enum as a string (rather than writing directly to a stream), because then I can incorporate its length into some wonky formatting calculations I want to do.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to implement `Display` by calling into `Debug`:

```
impl fmt::Display for Foo {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{:?}", self)
        // or, alternatively:
        // fmt::Debug::fmt(self, f)
    }
}
```

Then you can use `to_string()` to get a `String` representation:

```
let s: String = Foo::Quux.to_string();
```

If you have many enums which you want to print, you can [write a trivial macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64678145/7589775) to generate the above implementation of `Display` for each of them.

Unfortunately, in Rust reflective programming is somewhat difficult. There is no standard way, for example, to get a list of all variants of a C-like enum. Almost always you have to abstract the boilerplate with custom-written macros (or find something on crates.io). Maybe this will change in the future if someone would write an RFC and it would get accepted.

Comment: If you `use std::fmt::{self, Debug, Display}`, just calling `Debug::fmt(self, f)` is simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to put quotation marks around the output.

Comment: @DavidC.Bishop [No, it doesn't.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d6aef09223299d9692276c8e43677c5d) Of course, it will if you call Debug on the resulting string.

Comment: Even with @Veedrac's include, I'm getting this error: `use of undeclared crate or module `fmt``. Does this answer need to be updated for Rust 2021?

Comment: @RaleighL. It's been a while since I've touched Rust but I seriously doubt they've lost `std::fmt`; probably your imports are just bad somehow.

Comment: @RaleighL. you must have `use std::fmt` before writing `impl fmt::Display ...`, I think this is the most likely reason for your error.

Answer (score 62):

Since the names of enum variants are fixed, you don't need to allocate a `String`, a `&'static str` will suffice. A macro can remove the boilerplate:

```
macro_rules! enum_str {
    (enum $name:ident {
        $($variant:ident = $val:expr),*,
    }) => {
        enum $name {
            $($variant = $val),*
        }

        impl $name {
            fn name(&self) -> &'static str {
                match self {
                    $($name::$variant => stringify!($variant)),*
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

enum_str! {
    enum Foo {
        Bar = 0x00,
        Baz = 0x01,
        Qux = 0x02,
        //...
        Quux = 0xFF,
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(Foo::Baz.name(), "Baz");
}
```

Even better, you can derive these with a crate like [strum_macros](https://crates.io/crates/strum_macros).

In strum 0.10, you can use `AsStaticRef` / `AsStaticStr` to do the exact same code:

```
extern crate strum; // 0.10.0
#[macro_use]
extern crate strum_macros; // 0.10.0

use strum::AsStaticRef;

#[derive(AsStaticStr)]
enum Foo {
    Bar = 0x00,
    Baz = 0x01,
    Qux = 0x02,
    //...
    Quux = 0xFF,
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(Foo::Baz.as_static(), "Baz");
}
```

In strum 0.9, the string slice's lifetime is [not `'static` in this case](https://github.com/Peternator7/strum/issues/23):

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate strum_macros; // 0.9.0

#[derive(AsRefStr)]
enum Foo {
    Bar = 0x00,
    Baz = 0x01,
    Qux = 0x02,
    //...
    Quux = 0xFF,
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(Foo::Baz.as_ref(), "Baz");
}
```

Comment: This is the best one I have found. Now, there is another correction that can be done to make macro support both `Bar = 0x00` and `Bar` enum types. One with default and other without it. You can change `$($variant:ident = $val:expr),*,` --> `$($variant:ident = $($val:expr)?),*,` and `$($variant = $val),*` --> `$($variant:ident = $val:expr),*,`.
Now it is perfect!

Comment: Perhaps you even can use a `const fn` for `fn name()`?

Comment: @nalply yes, that should be possible in modern Rust versions.

Comment: With the firs solution, what if you wanted to use ```#[derive(Debug, Clone)]``` on ```enum Foo```?  ```enum_str!{#[derive(Debug, Clone)] enum Foo{Bar}}``` causes  ```no rules expected this token in macro call```

Comment: @ANimator120 you'd follow the steps outlined in [Generating documentation in macros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33999625/155423), which demonstrates how to handle the `meta` from the `derive`.

Answer (score -4):

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum SpreadsheetCell {
    Int(i32),
    Float(f64),
    Text(String),
}

pub fn enums_for_vector() {

    let row = vec![
        SpreadsheetCell::Int(3),
        SpreadsheetCell::Text(String::from("blue")),
        SpreadsheetCell::Float(10.12),
    ];

    for i in &row {
        let v = match i {
            SpreadsheetCell::Float(n) => n.to_string(),
            SpreadsheetCell::Int(i) => i.to_string(),
            SpreadsheetCell::Text(s) => s.to_string(),
        };
        println!("{}", v);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, would you mind adding some explanation why the already posted answers did not work for you and why your approach is better?

Comment: You should add explanation.