# Documenting a function created with a macro in Rust

Tags: macros, rust

I tried to do

```
#![deny(missing_docs)]
```

in Rust. And I found that `///` comments are just ignored when a function is created with a macro like this:

```
/// docs
py_module_initializer!(libx, initlibx PyInit_libx |py, m| {
    Ok(())
});
```

with:

```
error: missing documentation for a function
113 | py_module_initializer!(libx initlibx PyInit_libx |py, m| {
    | ^
```

I thought a macro will just add a function definition after `///`. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your doc comment refers to the macro invocation, which is useless in your case. To document the generated functions you have to write the doc comment into the macro definition *or* change your macro to also accept doc comments. Let's take a look at this:

```
#![deny(missing_docs)]
//! crate docs

macro_rules! gen_fn {
    ($name:ident) => {
        /// generic doc comment... not very useful
        pub fn $name() {}
    }
}

gen_fn!(a);
gen_fn!(b);
```

This works, but it's not the best solution, because doc comments are the same for all generated functions. If you want to document each generated function, you *have* to change the macro:

```
macro_rules! gen_fn {
    ($(#[$attr:meta])* => $name:ident) => {
        $(#[$attr])*
        pub fn $name() {}
    }
}

gen_fn!{
    /// Doc comment for a
    => a
}
```

This works, because doc comments are converted to the `#[doc(...)]` attribute internally. You can find more information about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999341/generating-documentation-in-macros).