# How can I generate doc in macros without transforming each line into a new paragraph?

Tags: rust, macros, metaprogramming, documentation

I learned [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41362344/6923555) that I can generate docs from macros:

```
macro_rules! gen_fn {
    (
        $(#[$attr: meta])*
        $name:ident
    ) => {
        $(#[$attr])*
        pub fn $name(self) {}
    }
}

struct Baz {}
impl Baz {
    gen_fn! {
        /// This is a doc
        /// with a very long text.
        my_func
    }
}

fn main() {
    let o = Baz{};
    o.my_func(); // generated method, with correct doc
}
```

However, if I pass more than one doc line to `gen_fn`, it interprets each line as a new `#[doc]`, thus transforming each line in to a new paragraph:

```
struct Baz {}
impl Baz {
    gen_fn! {
        /// This is a doc
        /// with a very long text.
        => my_func
    }
}
```

Instead of "This is a doc with a very long text"*, it becomes two paragraphs:

[image: Note how each line became a new paragraph]

How can I rewrite `gen_fn` so that it doesn't transform each new line into a paragraph?

#### Addendum:

I hacked out a way by directly inserting strings into a `#[doc]`, but it looks ugly, so I wonder if is there a more elegant way:

```
macro_rules! gen_fn {
    ($name: ident, $comm: expr) => {
        #[doc=$comm]
        pub fn $name(self) {}
    }
}

struct Baz {}
impl Baz {
    gen_fn!(my_func,
        "This is a doc
        with a very long text.");
}
```

---

#### Update:

This was indeed a bug in rust-analyzer, and it was fixed here:

- https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer/pull/6743

Comment: `error: no rules expected the token \`=>\``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks fine to me when documented via `cargo doc` with Rust 1.48.0:

[image: properly-formatted documentation]

```html
<div class="docblock"><p>This is a doc
with a very long text.</p>
</div>
```

The issue appears to be with how your editor is showing the documentation.

Comment: How can I generate this documentation locally?

Comment: Indeed, it looks like a problem of the parsing made by rust-analyzer. The generated doc is correct.