# How can I make a public struct where all fields are public without repeating `pub` for every field?

Tags: struct, rust, public, rust-macros

How can I define a public struct in Rust where all the fields are public without having to repeat the `pub` modifier in front of every field?

A `pub_struct` macro would be ideal:

```
pub_struct! Foo {
    a: i32,
    b: f64,
    // ...
}
```

which would be equivalent to:

```
pub struct Foo {
    pub a: i32,
    pub b: f64,
    //...
}
```

Comment: Let's be clear: you want a struct declaration without the first column precising what's public ? A macro can probably insert those modifiers but other readers of your code will have to learn your own special syntax to understand the whole is public...

Comment: So `pub Foo { pub a: u32, pub b: u32 }` is not what you are looking for?

Comment: Imo, specifying pub modifiers are good for the understandability of the code and should not be considered as boilerplate code. But what you want can be achieved via writing your own custom `#[derive(make_struct_pub)]` keyword.

Comment: You are solving the wrong problem. Just write `pub` in front of each field and be done with it. Repetition of code is bad because later changes to the code are error-prone – you may miss one of the repetitions. This is not an issue for writing `pub` in front of each field name. Even if you decide to change this later, there is little risk of getting it wrong.

Comment: Most of the comments so far are...unhelpful. @SvenMarnach macros exist to extend the language and keep code DRY. @Denys Seguret sorry, but I won't have you read my code - wouldn't wish it on my enemies. If you can help me write that macro, I would appreciate that. @Akiner, can you help me write a derive like that? A `pub_struct!` macro would be cool too.

Comment: @PetrusTheron, writing such a derive can be a crate sized work. To make an inspiration about the generation of such methods you can take a look at [getset crate](https://github.com/Hoverbear/getset) which is able to generate public getters and setters for you.

Comment: @AkinerAlkan You don't need procedural macros for this – macro by example will do just fine, and it's not difficult to implement. I just think it's _wrong_ to do so, so I won't spend my time on it.

Comment: I have RSI and it hurts when I type. I'm asking to save my wrists on big public structs. @SvenMarnach if you believe your view is correct and helpful, consider posting it as an answer. I say that the comments so far are unhelpful because they assume my intent ("solving the wrong problem") or question my competence (abusing or overusing macros). Rust isn't the first language to have macros, y'know? I believe the Rust community can benefit from posting empathetic answers rather than downvoting beginner questions just because they disagree with the premise.

Comment: @PetrusTheron You can use multiple cursors or keyboard macros in your editor to easily add `pub` in front of each line, which I consider the right solution. Using macros here makes the code harder to read for people who are new to the codebase, which I believe is the reason why people are downvoting. If you are determined to use macros anyway, you can start with a rule like `(struct $name:ident { $($field:ident : $type:ty,)* }) => { pub struct $name { $(pub $field: $type,)* } }` and refine it as needed to support generic parameters and field attributes.

Comment: Thanks, @SvenMarnach :) I got it working. See answer I posted. Wish I knew how to move the derive calls out of there, unfortunately `derive may only be applied to structs, enums and unions`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
macro_rules! pub_struct {
    ($name:ident {$($field:ident: $t:ty,)*}) => {
        #[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)] // ewww
        pub struct $name {
            $(pub $field: $t),*
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `derive` may only be applied to structs, enums and unions, so I don't know how to hoist those to the caller.

#### Usage:

```
pub_struct!(Foo {
    a: i32,
    b: f64,
});
```

It would be nice if I didn't need the parentheses and semicolon, i.e. if Rust supported reader macros.

Comment: [Rust's API guidelines recommend including the `struct` keyword in the macro syntax](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/api-guidelines/macros.html#input-syntax-is-evocative-of-the-output-c-evocative). This would also allow for [cleaner handling of the derive macros](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=61504b1b45811535371c28e8b55b7aae).

Comment: @SvenMarnach so maybe something like `pub! struct {a: i32, ...}`?

Comment: I don't think that's possible – there must be some kind of opening delimiter after the macro name.

Comment: @SvenMarnach you can remove the hardcoding of `derive`. See [Generating documentation in macros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33999341/155423)

Comment: @Shepmaster Please see the playground link in my comment above.

Comment: @SvenMarnach right... that's what I read and it hardcodes the word `derive`. I'm pointing out you don't need to do that. In addition, you expand the macro to support *any* attribute.

Comment: @Shepmaster Got it – I thought you meant the hard-coded derive in the answer. Sure, the solution could be made far more generic – it could support generic type parameters, field attributes and a visibility specifier for the struct itself, but I tried to keep it simple.