# Macro rule for matching a doc comment

Tags: rust, rust-macros

Is there a way to match doccomments in Rust's `macro_rules`?

I have a macro that generates an enum for a bunch of C constants that `bindgen` creates:

```
macro_rules! id_enum {
    ( enum $name:ident: $typ:ty { $( $enum_name:ident => $value:expr ),* , } ) => { ... }
}
```

I'd like to annotate each with a doc comment (a `///` comment), but that requires that my macro match the doc comments. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6):

Doc comments are translated to attributes of the form

```
#[doc = "documentation text"]
```

and can be matched in their translated form:

```
macro_rules! print_doc {
    (#[doc = $doc:expr]) => {
        pub fn foo() {
            println!($doc);
        }
    }
}

print_doc!(
    /// gloink
);

fn main() {
    foo();
}
```

If you want to emit the doc comment in modified form, you need to use the attribute syntax inside your macro, as explained in this answer:

- [Generating documentation in macros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33999625/279627)

To concatenate the original doc comment with your annotation, you can use the macro `concat!()` from the standard library. However, macro calls are not allowed inside attributes, so you need a helper macro, e.g.

```
macro_rules! annotated_func {
    ($doc:expr) => {
        #[doc = $doc]
        pub fn foo() {
            println!($doc);
        }
    }
}

macro_rules! print_doc {
    (#[doc = $doc:expr]) => {
        annotated_func!(concat!($doc, "\nannotation"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh cool, didn't know about the attribute form for docs. That would explain the "no rule to match `#`" error I got.