# How can I add rustdoc comments to proc macro-generated code?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-proc-macros

I wrote a `proc-macro` library to accompany a library I'm writing - they go together, with the former being used to abstract away a lot of redundant code in the latter.

I am successfully generating several structs and impls in my proc macro. I am also using `cargo doc` with the library, and my documentation is what I expect. However, the documentation comments I'm creating in my proc macro aren't working as expected. Some code from my proc macro looks roughly like this:

```rust
#[proc_macro_derive(MyDerive)]
pub fn derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    ...
    let expanded = quote! {
        ...
        impl #my_struct {
            /// This comment doesn't show up in documentation
            pub fn foo(&self, n: i32) -> bool {
               false
            }

            /// This comment DOES show up in documentation
            pub fn bar(n: i32) -> Vec<String> {
               ...
            }
        }
    }
    expanded.into()
}
```

When I open up the generated documentation:

- `foo` itself shows up in the documentation, but its comment doesn't
- `bar` and its comment are in the documentation
- If I change the comment for `bar`, the comment is *not* updated.

This third point tells me that I probably used some `cargo doc` flag at some point that works correctly, but I'm now using a different set of flags that don't work with proc macros. I don't want to document all my external crate dependencies (`--no-deps`), but I do want to document my private items (`--document-private-items`). I'm therefore generating docs with `cargo doc --no-deps --document-private-items`. I've also tried with `--release`.

I assume documentation is built from the source code and not from the built .so file itself, so I haven't been doing `cargo build` before doing `cargo doc`, though I have also tried this to debug this issue. So what is the right way to make sure my proc macro-generated code's documentation gets properly generated and updated?

Comment: Doesn't the method stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999341/generating-documentation-in-macros) work?

Comment: If you mean using the `#[doc="this is a comment"]` approach instead of `/// this is a comment` - no, that doesn't change the resulting generated docs.